# How can I exclude all "permission denied" messages from "find"?

Tags: bash, error-handling, find, file-permissions

I need to hide all *permission denied* messages from:

```
find . > files_and_folders
```

I am experimenting when such message arises. I need to gather all folders and files, to which it does not arise.

Is it possible to direct the permission levels to the `files_and_folders` file?

How can I hide the errors at the same time?

Comment: Great question!  Unfortunately, the first three answers simply do not work on Debian Linux.  Or at least my configuration of it.  I needed Fatih's solution, `find /. -name 'toBeSearched.file' 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: I found it best to exclude the `/proc` path using the `-path` option.  It helps to negate the `-prune` option to avoid printing pruned items.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

Note:

- This answer probably goes deeper than the use case warrants, and **`find 2>/dev/null` may be good enough in many situations**. It may still be of interest for a cross-platform perspective and for its discussion of some advanced shell techniques in the interest of finding a solution that is as robust as possible, even though the cases guarded against may be largely hypothetical.

---

If your **shell is `bash` or `zsh`**, there's **a solution that is robust while being reasonably simple**, using **only POSIX-compliant `find` features**; while `bash` itself is not part of POSIX, most modern Unix platforms come with it, making this solution widely portable:

```
find . > files_and_folders 2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2)
```

Note:

- **If your system is configured to show *localized* error messages, prefix the `find` calls below with `LC_ALL=C`**  (`LC_ALL=C find ...`) to ensure that *English* messages are reported, so that `grep -v 'Permission denied'` works as intended. Invariably, however, any error messages that *do* get displayed will then be in English as well.
- `>(...)` is a (rarely used) *output* [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) that allows redirecting output (in this case, *stderr* output (`2>`) to the stdin of the command inside `>(...)`.
  In addition to `bash` and `zsh`, `ksh` supports them as well *in principle*, but trying to combine them with redirection from *stderr*, as is done here (`2> >(...)`), appears to be silently ignored (in `ksh 93u+`).

  - `grep -v 'Permission denied'` filters *out* (`-v`) all lines (from the `find` command's stderr stream) that contain the phrase `Permission denied` and outputs the remaining lines to stderr (`>&2`).
  - Note: There's a small chance that some of `grep`'s output may arrive *after* `find` completes, because the overall command doesn't wait for the command inside `>(...)` to finish. In `bash`, you can prevent this by appending `| cat` to the command.

This approach is:

- **robust**: `grep` is only applied to *error messages* (and not to a combination of file paths and error messages, potentially leading to false positives), and error messages other than permission-denied ones are passed through, to stderr.
- **side-effect free**: `find`'s exit code is preserved: the inability to access at least one of the filesystem items encountered results in exit code `1` (although that won't tell you whether errors *other* than permission-denied ones occurred (too)).

---

#### POSIX-compliant solutions:

Fully POSIX-compliant solutions either have limitations or require additional work.

**If `find`'s output is to be captured in a *file* anyway** (or suppressed altogether), then the pipeline-based solution from [Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/762360/45375) is simple, robust, and POSIX-compliant:

```
find . 2>&1 >files_and_folders | grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2
```

Note that the order of the redirections matters: `2>&1` must come *first*.

Capturing stdout output in a file up front allows `2>&1` to send *only* error messages through the pipeline, which `grep` can then unambiguously operate on.

The **only downside is that the *overall exit code* will be the `grep` command's**, not `find`'s, which in this case means: if there are *no* errors at all or *only* permission-denied errors, the exit code will be `1` (signaling *failure*), otherwise (errors other than permission-denied ones) `0` - which is the opposite of the intent.
**That said, `find`'s exit code is rarely used anyway**, as it often conveys little information beyond *fundamental* failure such as passing a non-existent path.
However, the specific case of even only *some* of the input paths being inaccessible due to lack of permissions *is* reflected in `find`'s exit code (in both GNU and BSD `find`): if a permissions-denied error occurs for *any* of the files processed, the exit code is set to `1`.

The following variation addresses that:

```
find . 2>&1 >files_and_folders | { grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2; [ $? -eq 1 ]; }
```

Now, the exit code indicates whether any errors *other than* `Permission denied` occurred: `1` if so, `0` otherwise.
In other words: the exit code now reflects the true intent of the command: success (`0`) is reported, if no errors at all or *only* permission-denied errors occurred.
This is arguably even better than just passing `find`'s exit code through, as in the solution at the top.

---

[gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) in the comments proposes a (still POSIX-compliant) **generalization of this solution using sophisticated redirections**, which **works even with the default behavior of printing the file paths to *stdout***:

```
{ find . 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 | grep -v 'Permission denied' >&3; } 3>&2 2>&1
```

In short: Custom file descriptor `3` is used to temporarily swap stdout (`1`) and stderr (`2`), so that error messages *alone* can be piped to `grep` via stdout.

Without these redirections, both data (file paths) *and* error messages would be piped to `grep` via stdout, and `grep` would then not be able to distinguish between *error message* `Permission denied` and a (hypothetical) *file whose name happens to contain* the phrase `Permission denied`.

As in the first solution, however, the the exit code reported will be `grep`'s, not `find`'s, but the same fix as above can be applied.

---

#### Notes on the existing answers:

- There are several points to note about [Michael Brux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25234419/45375), `find . ! -readable -prune -o -print`:

  - It requires *GNU* `find`; notably, it won't work on macOS. Of course, if you only ever need the command to work with GNU `find`, this won't be a problem for you.
  - Some `Permission denied` errors may *still* surface: `find ! -readable -prune` reports such errors for the *child* items of directories for which the current user does have `r` permission, but lacks `x` (executable) permission. The reason is that because the directory itself *is* readable, `-prune` is not executed, and the attempt to descend *into* that directory then triggers the error messages. That said, the *typical* case is for the `r` permission to be missing.
  - Note: The following point is a matter of philosophy and/or specific use case, and you may decide it is not relevant to you and that the command fits your needs well, especially if simply *printing* the paths is all you do:

    - *If* you conceptualize the filtering of the permission-denied error messages a *separate* task that you want to be able to apply to *any* `find` command, then the opposite approach of proactively *preventing* permission-denied errors requires introducing "noise" into the `find` command, which also introduces complexity and logical *pitfalls*.
    - For instance, the most up-voted comment on Michael's answer (as of this writing) attempts to show how to *extend* the command by including a `-name` filter, as follows:
      `find . ! -readable -prune -o -name '*.txt'`
      This, however, does *not* work as intended, because the trailing `-print` action is *required* (an explanation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh)). Such subtleties can introduce bugs.
- The first solution in [Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/762360/45375), `find . 2>/dev/null > files_and_folders`, as he himself states,  **blindly silences *all* error messages** (and the workaround is cumbersome and not fully robust, as he also explains). **Pragmatically speaking**, however, it is the **simplest solution**, as you may be content to assume that any and all errors would be permission-related.
- [mist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27503763/45375), `sudo find . > files_and_folders`, **is concise and pragmatic, but ill-advised for anything other than merely *printing* filenames**, for security reasons: because you're running as the *root* user, "you risk having your whole system being messed up by a bug in find or a malicious version, or an incorrect invocation which writes something unexpectedly, which could not happen if you ran this with normal privileges" (from a comment on mist's answer by [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)).
- The 2nd solution in [viraptor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/762377/45375), `find . 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied' > some_file` runs the risk of false positives (due to sending a mix of stdout and stderr through the pipeline), and, potentially, instead of reporting *non*-permission-denied errors via stderr, captures them alongside the output paths in the output file.

Comment: Just a quick question: why do you use a process substitution and not just a pipe: `find . 2>&1 > files_and_folders | grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2`?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: If you don't want to output to an external file, just do more plumbing: `{ find . 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 | grep -v 'Permission denied' >&3; } 3>&2 2>&1`

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: Just that it's POSIX compliant. Process substitutions `>(...)` are Bash-specific.

Comment: I'm not sure that the preservation of the exit code of `find` should be emphasized and advertised: `find`'s exit code is notoriously useless. Here, it's very likely going to be non-zero (and uselessly so).

Comment: Why is this "reasonable simple" compared to "find . ! -readable ..."? It uses process substitution and grouping commands, what make things more complicated & what is maybe not needed for  Why should one use only POSIX compliant find features - but use bash or zsh at the same time? From my point of view the argument should be the operating system: GNU/Linux vs BSD vs macOS. How is your solution better compared to Jonathan Leffers answer? There is much more complexity added / much more text to read without any substantial benefit.

Comment: From my point of view the issue about "doesn't silence all Permission denied errors" can be an porting error or an error in macOS or an error in the underlying file system - but is no general argument against "find . ! -readable ...". Or not an argument against it in a GNU/Linux environment.

Comment: POSIX explicitly requires the `execute/search` file-mode permission in order to 'search' a directory (retrieve the inodes of contained files). `find` does this in order to descend into a subdirectory (in addition to requiring `read` permission to list the files in a directory). This is not a 'bug' or 'porting error'.

Comment: GNU/Linux vs. POSIX-environment discussion aside, I don't see how adding command-line options to the `find` command 'pollutes', 'obscures the actual intent', or makes it any 'harder to extend' - especially when being compared directly with alternative solutions involving pipelines, additional utilities, error-stream redirection, etc.

Comment: GNU `find` can be installed on macOS: `brew install findutils`.

Comment: TLDR,  find . -name myname 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied" (when not building a rocket ship, but trying to find a file)

Answer (score 663):

Use:

```
find . 2>/dev/null > files_and_folders
```

This hides not just the `Permission denied` errors, of course, but all error messages.

If you really want to keep other possible errors, such as too many hops on a symlink, but not the permission denied ones, then you'd probably have to take a flying guess that you don't have many files called 'permission denied' and try:

```
find . 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied' > files_and_folders
```

---

If you strictly want to filter just standard error, you can use the more elaborate construction:

```
find . 2>&1 > files_and_folders | grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2
```

The I/O redirection on the `find` command is: `2>&1 > files_and_folders |`.
The pipe redirects standard output to the `grep` command and is applied first.  The `2>&1` sends standard error to the same place as standard output (the pipe). The `> files_and_folders` sends standard output (but not standard error) to a file.  The net result is that messages written to standard error are sent down the pipe and the regular output of `find` is written to the file.  The `grep` filters the standard output (you can decide how selective you want it to be, and may have to change the spelling depending on locale and O/S) and the final `>&2` means that the surviving error messages (written to standard output) go to standard error once more. The final redirection could be regarded as optional at the terminal, but would be a very good idea to use it in a script so that error messages appear on standard error.

There are endless variations on this theme, depending on what you want to do.  This will work on any variant of Unix with any Bourne shell derivative (Bash, Korn, …) and any POSIX-compliant version of [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).

If you wish to adapt to the specific version of `find` you have on your system, there may be alternative options available.  GNU `find` in particular has a myriad options not available in other versions — see the currently accepted answer for one such set of options.

Comment: If you are like me, notice that lack of space is important! `2>/dev/null`, without space!

Comment: The `2>` is a single unit without any spaces; you can have a space between it and the file name. Similarly with other redirections, such as `2>&1` (which redirects standard error to the same place as standard output is going), or `2>&-` which closes standard error, etc. See [Redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) for the remaining gory details. (The code above is generic POSIX-like shell, not specific to `bash`.)

Comment: @DavidDoria you can use `grep -i` or (in this case) `grep -vi` to ignore case.

Comment: How is this an acceptable solution? 1) You're redirecting ALL errors to dev/null 2) You're filtering an explicit error string!! Depending on these is famously brittle and what if your file was in a directory named 'permission denied'? Oops!

Comment: @Gunchars: the points you raise are covered in the answer — or the explicit error string is covered by the specification of the question.  The first command does send all errors to `/dev/null`; the second does not.  And the answer mentions the assumption that you don't have any files called `permission denied`.  So, I'm not clear what you're really objecting to.

Comment: I'm objecting against grepping error strings to modify program's output. It will work most of the time, but simple isn't the correct solution (find with perms below is). To give you an example why, this will not work on OSX because the error is "Permission denied". Same for any other system where there's even minuscule differences in the error string (internationalization anyone?)

Comment: To make grep-ing somewhat more robust, better use `LANG=C grep` as, depending on localization, messages will otherwise vary and grep won't match them. Still not as solid as user3701456's answer.

Comment: @ThomasW: Good point, but it is the `find` command (not `grep`) you must prefix with `LANG=C` (or, slightly more robustly, `LC_ALL=C`).

Comment: I don't understand how to use this answer. How would you search Desktop for Pizza?

Comment: this question is about how to filter certain error messages from an otherwise working `find` command; it isn't a tutorial on how to use `find`.  On the face of it, you'd be running `find ~/Desktop -name Pizza`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know how to find pizza in desktop. But how would I do so while also muting the above errors? Where in that command would the usual “-name pizza” stuff go?

Comment: You can put the I/O redirection more or less wherever you like on the command line, provided you keep them in the correct sequence.  So, you can write `2>&1 find > files_and_folders ~/Desktop -name Pizza` or `find  2>&1 ~/Desktop -name > files_and_folders Pizza` or (more conventionally), `find ~/Desktop -name Pizza 2>&1 > files_and_folders` (with the output, in each case, piped to an appropriate `grep` command).  Experimentation is good — and a `find` command is pretty harmless (as long as you don't scan the entire file system).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I ran this in my parent folder of all my repos, and got no output at all: `find 2>&1 . -name > files_and_folders "README.md"` - does this type of find command not search subdirectories? I do find them if I simply run `find . -name "README.md"` - also, this command seems to create files all over the place..! That's a bit scary. Such as files named "files_and_folders" and "README.md"

Answer (score 314):

Use:

```
find . ! -readable -prune -o -print
```

or more generally

```
find <paths> ! -readable -prune -o <other conditions like -name> -print
```

- to avoid "Permission denied"
- AND do NOT suppress (other) error messages
- AND get exit status 0 ("all files are processed successfully")

Works with: find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2.
Background:

- The `-readable` test matches readable files. The `!` operator returns true, when test is false. And `! -readable` matches not readable directories (&files).
- The `-prune` action does not descend into directory.
- `! -readable -prune` can be translated to: if directory is not readable, do not descend into it.
- The `-readable` test takes into account access control lists and other permissions artefacts  which  the `-perm` test ignores.

See also [`find`(1) manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for many more details.

Comment: How is this better or worser than Jonathan's answer? Do both have the same outputs?

Comment: the differences are already mentioned. if you don't understand, then the answers maybe make no difference for you? STDOUT is the same - STDERR is different (you get the other error messages with this answer) - $? is different (is 0 "successful" with this answer, when no other error occurs - is always > 0 "not successfull" when redirecting to dev/null) - maybe someone needs "correct" $? in a script

Comment: I think this is the more elegant solution of the thread. I like the successful result $?.

Comment: @Masi the most obvious flaw is Jonathan's answer(grep -v) will exclude filename which contains 'Permission denied' :)

Comment: I feel it appropriate to add here that if you need to add some other search criteria, that should be done with `-o`: `find . ! -readable -prune -o -name '*.txt'`

Comment: Note that POSIX `find` does not include `-readable` as an option; neither does the `find` for BSD and hence Mac OS X (I'm not sure about other systems).  So, where you have GNU `find` guaranteed, this works great, but it isn't obvious how to adapt this if you can't guarantee that the system has GNU `find` installed.  (It'll work fine on Linux; it may or may not work elsewhere.)

Comment: `find . ! -readable -prune -o -name '*.txt'` doen't seem to work on Ubuntu 14.04 using find 4.2.2. It seems to ingore the `-name`. For some weird reason I has success with `find . \( ! -readable -prune \) -o -name '*.txt' -print`

Comment: @con-f-use - I had the same issue, I found I only needed the `-print`, not the complicated brackets.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to ignore non-existentent paths? E.g., if I have `find path1 path2 path3 -type f`, I don't want find to give an error even if the paths are missing. Otherwise, I have to construct the path list in advance by checking which ones exist and not having any path is not an error condition for me.

Comment: @con-f-use See additional explanation re: brackets and `-print` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh

Comment: @haridsv: No: `find` invariably complains about nonexistent _input_ paths. You'll have to use one of the solutions that filter `find`'s stderr output and filter out `No such file or directory` messages.

Comment: @MichaelBrux: A belated ++; the discussion below my answer went on, and the updated version is hopefully more balanced. A readable but non-executable dir. still causing permission-denied errors for its child items is not a bug, after all: since the directory itself is readable, `-prune` doesn't kick in, and accessing the child items then fails (due to lack of executable permissions on the dir). As stated, though, it is an exotic case.

Comment: Could this be restricted further to prune directories which are not executable in addition to not readable?

Comment: @AndrewMcKinlay
see https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Mode-Bits
GNU find supports -executable test

Comment: @con-f-use your command worked because you added `-print` to the end.  That acted on the matches of `-name '*.txt'.`  When you add `-print` to one of the clauses in the `-o` (logical OR), find knows that you only want to print that part.  Otherwise, if defaults to printing everything it finds.  And the unreadable thing was "found", although not readable.   (...as described well in the link that DreadPirateShawn posted, now that I pay attention)

Comment: Maybe you want to use `! -readable -prune -false` to suppress unreadable directories (and not only the warning)

Comment: as a note, doesn't appear to work in a cygwin/msys env

Comment: When you want to find files by name, you might still want to find unreadable files and only skip unreadable dirs with `\( ! -readable -type d -prune \) -o \( -name "*.foo" -print \)`. For example, `find /etc \( ! -readable -type d -prune \) -o \( -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*\.dpkg-(old|dist)" -print \)`.

Answer (score 123):

If you want to start search from root "/" , you will probably see output somethings like:

```
find: /./proc/1731/fdinfo: Permission denied
find: /./proc/2032/task/2032/fd: Permission denied
```

It's because of permission.  To solve this:

1. You can use sudo command:

   ```
   sudo find /. -name 'toBeSearched.file'
   ```

It asks super user's password, when enter the password you will see result what you really want. If you don't have permission to use sudo command which means you don't have super user's password, first ask system admin to add you to the sudoers file.

2. You can use redirect the Standard Error Output from (Generally Display/Screen) to some file and avoid seeing the error messages on the screen! redirect to a special file /dev/null :

   ```
   find /. -name 'toBeSearched.file' 2>/dev/null
   ```
3. You can use redirect the Standard Error Output from (Generally Display/Screen) to Standard output (Generally Display/Screen), then pipe with grep command with -v "invert" parameter to not to see the output lines which has 'Permission denied' word pairs:

   ```
   find /. -name 'toBeSearched.file' 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied'
   ```

Comment: @scottmrogowski except that it doesn't answer the question... 1. ask system admin to add you to the sudoers file. 2. `sudo find...`

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: It's been a while since I found the right answer after reading four high-voted, page-long answers that were all incorrect.  Thank you!

Comment: mulling all this over `Permission Denied` is not a bad thing.  If you are searching and don't get that error (filtered it per OP) and say you wanted to search /etc but you don't have read permissions for some directories therein then you get potentially no or limited results when there were possible matches...yikes!  So use 2 or 3 or the answer right above this one only after being sure you don't want to search in the permission denied directories.  Otherwise prefacing with sudo or being granted permissions on said directories is the only option to search them.

Answer (score 108):

I had to use:

```
find / -name expect 2>/dev/null
```

specifying the name of what I wanted to find and then telling it to redirect all errors to /dev/null

expect being the location of the expect program I was searching for.

Comment: @Masi, the command in the answer doesn't use `expect`. Instead, `expect` is simply the name of the file that this command will try to find.

Comment: Blindly redirecting all stderr output just to ignore a single class of error messages is generally a bad idea - you will lose all other arbitrary errors in the process.

Answer (score 72):

Pipe `stderr` to `/dev/null` by using **2>/dev/null**

`find . -name '...' 2>/dev/null`

Comment: This works fine for me even on Mac OSX. Or even `find . -name '...' -print 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 31):

You can also use the `-perm` and `-prune` predicates to avoid descending into unreadable directories (see also [How do I remove "permission denied" printout statements from the find program? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19430/how-do-i-remove-permission-denied-printout-statements-from-the-find-program/121020#121020)):

```
find . -type d ! -perm -g+r,u+r,o+r -prune -o -print > files_and_folders
```

Comment: `-perm -g+r,u+r,o+r` merely matches files that have the `r` (read) permission set for all 3 of the _file's_ security principals, which has no direct relationship with whether the _current user_ can read that  file or not.
It has the potential to both miss files that the current user _can_ read and to match files that they cannot.

Comment: I think `find . -type d ! \( -perm -u+r -o -perm -g+r -o -perm -o+r \) -prune -o -print` would be the good solution.

Comment: @Mattia72: No, it is fundamentally impossible to fully emulate `-readable` with `-perm` - see my previous comment and consider this example: `echo 'hi' > file; sudo chown nobody:nobody file; sudo chmod o-r file; find file -perm -u=r` prints `file`, because its user read bit is set, but it relates to the the `nobody` user, not the current user. The current user cannot read this file; try `cat file`. See also: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458120/unix-find-search-for-executable-files/29039160#29039160) of mine.

Answer (score 23):

Redirect standard error. For instance, if you're using bash on a unix machine, you can redirect standard error to /dev/null like this:

```
find . 2>/dev/null >files_and_folders
```

Answer (score 20):

While above approaches do not address the case for Mac OS X because Mac Os X does not support `-readable` switch this is how you can avoid 'Permission denied' errors in your output. This might help someone.

`find / -type f -name "your_pattern" 2>/dev/null`.

If you're using some other command with `find`, for example, to find the size of files of certain pattern in a directory `2>/dev/null` would still work as shown below.

`find . -type f  -name "your_pattern" -exec du -ch {} + 2>/dev/null | grep total$`.

This will return the total size of the files of a given pattern. Note the `2>/dev/null` at the end of find command.

Comment: Nice binding to the OS X! Jonathan's answer explains the part `2>/dev/null`. Can you please explain the part `-exec du -ch {} + 2>/dev/null | grep total$`.

Comment: @Masi You can use any command with `-exec` option to take further action on the files or directories found by `find` command. `du -ch file_pattern` calculates the size of each file matching `file_pattern` and last line of that output is the grand total of all files that matched the `file_pattern`. See man page for `du`. `grep total` just filters the line that extracts the grand total(which is the last line).

Answer (score 13):

Those errors are printed out to the standard error output (fd 2). To filter them out, simply redirect all errors to /dev/null:

```
find . 2>/dev/null > some_file
```

or first join stderr and stdout and then grep out those specific errors:

```
find . 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied' > some_file
```

Answer (score 13):

### Simple answer:

`find . > files_and_folders 2>&-`

*[`2>&-`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_06) closes (`-`) the standard error file descriptor (`2`) so all error messages are silenced.*

- Exit code will still be `1` if any '`Permission denied`' errors would otherwise be printed

### Robust answer for GNU `find`:

`find . -type d \! \( -readable -executable \) -prune -print -o -print > files_and_folders`

*Pass extra options to `find` that [`-prune`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_002dprune-48) (prevent descending into) but still [`-print`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_002dprint-66) any directory ([`-type`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_002dtype-31)`d`) that does not ([`\!`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_0021-57)) have both [`-readable`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_002dreadable-39) and [`-executable`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_002dexecutable-41) permissions, or ([`-o`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_002do-62)) `-print` any other file.*

- [`-readable`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_002dreadable-39) and [`-executable`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_002dexecutable-41) options are GNU extensions, not part of the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)
- May still return '`Permission denied`' on abnormal/corrupt files (e.g., see [bug report](https://github.com/lxc/lxcfs/issues/149) affecting container-mounted filesystems using `lxcfs` < v2.0.5)

### Robust answer that works with any POSIX-compatible `find` (GNU, OSX/BSD, etc)

`{ LC_ALL=C find . 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 > files_and_folders | grep -v 'Permission denied'; [ $? = 1 ]; } 3>&2 2>&1`

*Use a [pipeline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02) to pass the standard error stream to [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), removing all lines containing the `'Permission denied'` string.*

*`LC_ALL=C` sets the [POSIX locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_02) using an [environment variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_02), `3>&2 2>&1 1>&3` and `3>&2 2>&1` [duplicate file descriptors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_06) to pipe the standard-error stream to `grep`, and `[ $? = 1 ]` uses [`[]`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) to invert the error code returned by `grep` to approximate the original behavior of `find`.*

- Will also filter any `'Permission denied'` errors due to output redirection (e.g., if the `files_and_folders` file itself is not writable)

Comment: How do you think about JordiFerran's answer proposal? - - Can you compare your answer to it?

Comment: That answer's shell script as stated is not general-purpose (only lists directories matching ${m_find_name}), and contains several options not relevant to the question (nice, /home*, -maxdepth 5, -follow). This answer addresses the specific issue of 'filtering readable but not executable directories' more concisely, while remaining general-purpose.

Comment: @wjordan: Thanks. I've removed my comments, but one point still applies: the `-perm`-based solution is not worth presenting, because it more fundamentally than the quote suggests does something _different_ than intended: it is a purely _file-centric_ test, relating to the _file's_ owner and group, neither of which have any guaranteed relationship with the user calling the command (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29039160/45375) of mine. It looks like your revised GNU solution now doesn't catch permission denied errors stemming from _files_.

Comment: I don't recognize the syntax you're using (neither as GNU nor as BSD), but let me illustrate my point with a self-contained example: `echo 'hi' > file; sudo chown nobody:nobody file; sudo chmod o-r file; find file -perm -u=r` prints `file`, because its user read bit is set, but it relates to the the `nobody` user, not the current user. The current user cannot read this file; try `cat file`.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for the discussion, i managed to produce the behavior you described in another test (don't know what I did wrong the first time), it does seem that `-perm` doesn't work for determining the user's current permissions. Removed that alternative from this answer.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid *just* the permission denied warnings, tell find to ignore the unreadable files by pruning them from the search. Add an expression as an OR to your find, such as

```
find / \! -readable -prune -o -name '*.jbd' -ls
```

This mostly says to *(match an unreadable file and prune it from the list)* OR *(match a name like* *.jbd *and display it [with ls])*. (Remember that by default the expressions are AND'd together unless you use -or.) You need the -ls in the second expression or else find may add a default action to show either match, which will also show you all the unreadable files.

But if you're looking for real files on your system, there is usually no reason to look in /dev, which has many many files, so you should add an expression that excludes that directory, like:

```
find / -mount \! -readable -prune  -o  -path /dev -prune  -o  -name '*.jbd' -ls
```

So *(match unreadable file and prune from list)* OR *(match path /dev and prune from list)* OR *(match file like* *.jbd *and display it)*.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use this to search for a file in your system.

`find / -name YOUR_SEARCH_TERM 2>&1 | grep YOUR_SEARCH_TERM`

Let's not do unnecessary over engineering, you just want to search for your file right? then that is the command which will list the files for you if they are present in an area accessible to you.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
sudo find / -name file.txt
```

It's stupid (because you elevate the search) and nonsecure, but far shorter to write.

Comment: You search here the whole filesystem so you mean by this "elevate the search". Why do you call it nonsecure? Because it is searching whole filesystem?

Comment: Because sudo runs the find command with root permissions which basically is a bad idea. Segregation and least-privilege principles are violated.

Comment: The "elevation" here is of the privileges, to root, with `sudo`.  You risk having your whole system being messed up by a bug in `find` or a malicious version, or an incorrect invocation which writes something unexpectedly, which could not happen if you ran this with normal privileges.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers worked for me. Whatever I find on Internet focuses on: hide errors. None properly handles the process return-code / exit-code. I use command find within bash scripts to locate some directories and then inspect their content. I evaluate command find success using the exit-code: a value zero works, otherwise fails.

The [answer provided above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find/25234419#25234419) by [Michael Brux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3701456/michael-brux) works sometimes. But I have one scenario in which it fails! I discovered the problem and fixed it myself. I need to prune files when:

```
it is a directory AND has no read access AND/OR has no execute access
```

See the key issue here is: AND/OR. One good suggested condition sequence I read is:

```
-type d ! -readable ! -executable -prune
```

This does not work always. This means a prune is triggered when a match is:

```
it is directory AND no read access AND no execute access
```

This sequence of expressions fails when read access is granted but no execute access is.

After some testing I realized about that and changed my shell script solution to:

> nice find /home*/ -maxdepth 5 -follow \
>       \( -type d -a **! \( -readable -a -executable \)** \) -prune \
>       -o \
>       \( -type d -a -readable -a -executable -a -name "${m_find_name}" \) -print

The key here is to place the "not true" for a combined expression:

```
has read access AND has execute access
```

Otherwise it has not full access, which means: prune it. This proved to work for me in one scenario which previous suggested solutions failed.

I provide below technical details for questions in the comments section. I apologize if details are excessive.

- ¿Why using command nice? I got the idea [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19430/how-do-i-remove-permission-denied-printout-statements-from-the-find-program/19433#19433). Initially I thought it would be nice to reduce process priority when looking an entire filesystem. I realized it makes no sense to me, as my script is limited to few directories. I reduced -maxdepth to 3.
- ¿Why search within /home*/? This it not relevant for this thread. I install all applications by hand via source code compile with non privileged users (not root). They are installed within "/home". I can have multiple binaries and versions living together. I need to locate all directories, inspect and backup in a master-slave fashion. I can have more than one "/home" (several disks running within a dedicated server).
- ¿Why using -follow? Users might create symbolic links to directories. It's usefulness depends, I need to keep record of the absolute paths found.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and nice observations! I opened a bounty here to preview your answer better. I think it is a nice finding not prevent read and execute access. - - Can you please explain why you use `nice` and `find $HOME -maxdepth 5 -follow ...`?

Comment: The shell script as stated is not general-purpose (only lists directories matching `${m_find_name}`), and contains several options not relevant to the question (`nice`, `/home*`, `-maxdepth 5`, `-follow`). I've added an answer that addresses the specific issue of 'filtering readable but not executable directories' more concisely, while remaining general-purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the grep -v invert-match

```
-v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
```

like this:

```
find . > files_and_folders
cat files_and_folders | grep -v "permission denied" > files_and_folders
```

Should to the magic

Answer (score 2):

-=For MacOS=-

Make a new command using alias: just add in ~/.bash_profile line:

```
alias search='find / -name $file 2>/dev/null'
```

and in new Terminal window you can call it:

```
$ file=<filename or mask>; search
```

> for example:
>
> $ file=etc; search

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CSH or TCSH, here is a solution:

```
( find . > files_and_folders ) >& /dev/null
```

If you want output to the terminal:

```
( find . > /dev/tty ) >& /dev/null
```

However, [as the "csh-whynot" FAQ describes, you should not use CSH.](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Comment: I want to grep all txt files and exclude hidden files/directory, omit "Permission denied" message to be printed. I am using csh shell. 

I have used below commands and they are not working 
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -not -path '*/\.*' | egrep -v "Permission denied"

find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -not -path '*/\.*' 2>/dev/null

Getting below Error. 

find: paths must precede expression: 2
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Answer (score 1):

### Optimized solutions for GNU `find`<sup>†</sup>

At least for some system+filesystem combinations, `find` doesn't need to `stat` a file to get its type. Then you can check if it's a directory before testing readability to speed up the search<sup>‡</sup> —I've got some 30% improvement in tests I did. So for long searches or searches that run often enough, use one of these:

**Print everything visible**

```
$ find . -print -type d ! -readable -prune
$ find . -type d ! -readable -prune , [expression] -print
```

**Print visible *files***

```
$ find . -type d \( ! -readable -prune -o -true \) -o [expression] -print
```

**Print visible directories**

```
$ find . -type d -print ! -readable -prune
$ find . -type d \( ! -readable -prune , [expression] -print \)
```

**Print only *readable* directories**

```
$ find . -type d ! -readable -prune -o [expression] -print
```

---

#### Notes

<sup>†</sup> The `-readable` and `,` (comma) operators are GNU extensions. This expression

```
$ find . [expression] , [expression]
```

is *logically equivalent* to

```
$ find . \( [expression] -o -true \) [expression]
```

<sup>‡</sup> This is because `find` implementations with this optimization enabled will avoid `stat`ing non-directory files at all in the discussed use case.

---

#### Edit: shell function

Here is a POSIX shell function I ended up with to prepend this test to any expression. It seems to work fine with the implicit `-print` and command-line options:

```
findr () {
    j=$#; done=
    while [ $j -gt 0 ]; do
        j=$(($j - 1))
        arg="$1"; shift
        test "$done" || case "$arg" in
            -[A-Z]*) ;;  # skip options
            -*|\(|!)     # find start of expression
                set -- "$@" \( -type d ! -readable -prune -o -true \)
                done=true
                ;;
        esac
        set -- "$@" "$arg"
    done
    find "$@"
}
```

The other two alternatives listed in the answers caused either a syntax error in POSIX shell (couldn't even source a file containing the function definition) or bad output in ZSH... Running time seems to be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

To search the entire file system for some file, e.g. `hosts`, except the `/proc` tree, which causes all kinds of errors, I use the following:

```
# find / -path /proc ! -prune -o -name hosts -type f
/etc/hosts
```

Note: Because `-prune` is *always true*, you have to negate it to avoid seeing the line `/proc` in the output.   I tried the using `! -readable` approach and found it returns all kinds of things under /proc that the current user *can* read.   So the "OR" condition doesn't do what you expect/want there.

I started with the example given by the [find man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), See the `-prune` option.

Answer (score -3):

Minimal solution is just to add the `readable` flag.

`find . -name foo -readable`