# How to use '-prune' option of 'find' in sh?

Tags: regex, shell, find, manual

I don't quite understand the example given from the `man find`, can anyone give me some examples and explanations? Can I combine regular expression in it?

---

The more detailed question is like this:

Write a shell script, `changeall`, which has an interface like `changeall [-r|-R] "string1" "string2"`. It will find all files with an suffix of `.h`, `.C`, `.cc`, or `.cpp` and change all occurrences of `string1` to `string2`. `-r` is option for staying in current dir only or including subdir's.

NOTE:

1. For non-recursive case, `ls` is NOT allowed, we could only use `find` and `sed`.
2. I tried `find -depth` but it was NOT supported. That's why I was wondering if `-prune` could help, but didn't understand the example from `man find`.

---

EDIT2: I was doing assignment, I didn't ask question in great details because I would like to finish it myself. Since I already done it and hand it in, now I can state the whole question. Also, I managed to finish the assignment without using `-prune`, but would like to learn it anyway.

Answer (score 564, accepted):

The thing I'd found confusing about `-prune` is that it's an action (like `-print`), not a test (like `-name`). It alters the "to-do" list, *but always returns true*.

The general pattern for using `-prune` is this:

```
find [path] [conditions to prune] -prune -o \
            [your usual conditions] [actions to perform]
```

You pretty much always want the `-o` (logical OR) immediately after `-prune`, because that first part of the test (up to and including `-prune`) will return *false* for the stuff you actually want (ie: the stuff you *don't* want to prune out).

Here's an example:

```
find . -name .snapshot -prune -o -name '*.foo' -print
```

This will find the "*.foo" files that aren't under ".snapshot" directories. In this example, `-name .snapshot` makes up the `[conditions to prune]`, and `-name '*.foo' -print` is `[your usual conditions]` and `[actions to perform]`.

**Important notes**:

1. If all you want to do is print the results you might be used to leaving out the `-print` action. You generally *don't* want to do that when using `-prune`.

   The default behavior of find is to "and" the *entire* expression with the `-print` action if there are no actions other than `-prune` (ironically) at the end. That means that writing this:

   ```
    find . -name .snapshot -prune -o -name '*.foo'              # DON'T DO THIS
   ```

   is equivalent to writing this:

   ```
    find . \( -name .snapshot -prune -o -name '*.foo' \) -print # DON'T DO THIS
   ```

   which means that it'll also print out the name of the directory you're pruning, which usually isn't what you want. Instead it's better to explicitly specify the `-print` action if that's what you want:

   ```
    find . -name .snapshot -prune -o -name '*.foo' -print       # DO THIS
   ```
2. If your "usual condition" happens to match files that also match your prune condition, those files will *not* be included in the output. The way to fix this is to add a `-type d` predicate to your prune condition.

   For example, suppose we wanted to prune out any directory that started with `.git` (this is admittedly somewhat contrived -- normally you only need to remove the thing named *exactly* `.git`), but other than that wanted to see all files, including files like `.gitignore`. You might try this:

   ```
   find . -name '.git*' -prune -o -type f -print               # DON'T DO THIS
   ```

   This would *not* include `.gitignore` in the output. Here's the fixed version:

   ```
   find . -name '.git*' -type d -prune -o -type f -print       # DO THIS
   ```

Extra tip: if you're using the GNU version of `find`, [the texinfo page for `find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/find.html) has a more detailed explanation than its manpage (as is true for most GNU utilities).

Comment: and +1 for you for the nicely done explanation (and especially the important note). You should submit this to the find developpers (as the man page doesn't explain "prune" for normal human beings ^^ It took me many tries to figure it out, and I didn't see that side effect you warns us about)

Comment: You can also use this in conjunction with an `-exec` clause to 'mark' a directory with a particular file indicating it should not be descended into. For this you need to use the multiline `-exec` version shown in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507025/369126  and could look like:

  `find $dir -type d -exec sh -c 'test -f $1/DONTBACKUP' sh {} \; -prune -o morestuff`

We start at `$dir` , and any directory found is tested for it containing a file called `DONTBACKUP`. If it's there (exit status of the `-exec` is 0, i.e. succes) that dir is skipped, otherwise we continue with `morestuff`

Comment: At the expense of more compute cycles, I am often able to avoid `-prune` using `\! -path`. For example, to avoid descending into folders named `archive`, I use `find folder1 folder2 \! -path '*/archive/*'`.

Comment: In my case it returns the excluding directory (but not the content) with this command: `find . -name "*.c" -o -path "./build" -prune`. So it returns a bunch of `*.c` files that are not in `./build/` and `./build/`

Comment: @Puck You need to add an explicit `-print` action to get the right behavior. You've got your clauses backward from the way recommended in the answer. I'd normally write what you're trying to do as: `find . -path "./build" -prune -o -name "*.c" -print`. However, if you prefer the pruned stuff last that can work too, but you need to insert the print action before the `-o`: `find . -name "*.c" -print -o -path "./build" -prune`. See "Important note" #1 for more details.

Comment: @user2153235 This is a great tip! `\! -path` is a lot easier to understand, and works well for the common case of pruning by path name. However, `-prune` is more versatile, because it can prune based on any predicate, not just the path.

Comment: This is a great answer especially when combined with [@AmitP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14648883/61624) about ordering the command.

Answer (score 40):

Normally, the native way we do things in Linux, and the way we think, is from left to right.

You would go and write what you are looking for first:

```
find / -name "*.php"
```

Then, you hit ENTER and realize you are getting too many files from directories you wish not to.

So, you think "let's exclude `/media` to avoid searching mounted drives."

You should now just *append* the following to the previous command:

```
-print -o -path '/media' -prune
```

and the final command is:

```sh
find / -name "*.php" -print -o -path '/media' -prune
```

```
|<--      Include      -->|<--      Exclude      -->|
```

I think this structure is much easier and correlates to the right approach.

Answer (score 32):

Beware that -prune does not prevent descending into **any** directory as some have said. It prevents descending into directories that match the test it's applied to. Perhaps some examples will help (see the bottom for a regex example). Sorry for this being so lengthy.

```
$ find . -printf "%y %p\n"    # print the file type the first time FYI
d .
f ./test
d ./dir1
d ./dir1/test
f ./dir1/test/file
f ./dir1/test/test
d ./dir1/scripts
f ./dir1/scripts/myscript.pl
f ./dir1/scripts/myscript.sh
f ./dir1/scripts/myscript.py
d ./dir2
d ./dir2/test
f ./dir2/test/file
f ./dir2/test/myscript.pl
f ./dir2/test/myscript.sh

$ find . -name test
./test
./dir1/test
./dir1/test/test
./dir2/test

$ find . -prune
.

$ find . -name test -prune
./test
./dir1/test
./dir2/test

$ find . -name test -prune -o -print
.
./dir1
./dir1/scripts
./dir1/scripts/myscript.pl
./dir1/scripts/myscript.sh
./dir1/scripts/myscript.py
./dir2

$ find . -regex ".*/my.*p.$"
./dir1/scripts/myscript.pl
./dir1/scripts/myscript.py
./dir2/test/myscript.pl

$ find . -name test -prune -regex ".*/my.*p.$"
(no results)

$ find . -name test -prune -o -regex ".*/my.*p.$"
./test
./dir1/test
./dir1/scripts/myscript.pl
./dir1/scripts/myscript.py
./dir2/test

$ find . -regex ".*/my.*p.$" -a -not -regex ".*test.*"
./dir1/scripts/myscript.pl
./dir1/scripts/myscript.py

$ find . -not -regex ".*test.*"                   .
./dir1
./dir1/scripts
./dir1/scripts/myscript.pl
./dir1/scripts/myscript.sh
./dir1/scripts/myscript.py
./dir2
```

Answer (score 22):

Adding to the advice given in other answers (I have no rep to create replies)...

When combining `-prune` with other expressions, there is a subtle difference in behavior depending on which other expressions are used.

@Laurence Gonsalves' example will find the "*.foo" files that aren't under ".snapshot" directories:-

```
find . -name .snapshot -prune -o -name '*.foo' -print
```

However, this slightly different short-hand will, perhaps inadvertently, also list the `.snapshot` directory (and any nested .snapshot directories):-

```
find . -name .snapshot -prune -o -name '*.foo'
```

According to the [posix manpage](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#:%7E:text=If%20no%20expression%20is%20present), the reason is:

> If the given expression does not contain any of the primaries -exec,
> -ls, -ok, or -print, the given expression is effectively replaced by:
>
> ( given_expression ) -print

That is, the second example is the equivalent of entering the following, thereby modifying the grouping of terms:-

```
find . \( -name .snapshot -prune -o -name '*.foo' \) -print
```

This has at least been seen on Solaris 5.10. Having used various flavors of *nix for approx 10 years, I've only recently searched for a reason why this occurs.

Answer (score 5):

I am no expert at this (and this page was very helpful along with http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)

Just noticed `-path` is for a path that **fully matches the string/path that comes just after `find`** (`.` in theses examples) where as `-name` matches all basenames.

```
find . -path ./.git  -prune -o -name file  -print
```

blocks the .git directory in your current directory **(** as your finding in `.` **)**

```
find . -name .git  -prune -o -name file  -print
```

blocks all .git subdirectories recursively.

Note  the `./`  is extremely important!!  `-path` must match a path anchored to `.` **or whatever comes just after find** if you  get matches with out it (from the other side of the or '`-o`') there probably not being pruned!
I was naively unaware of this and it put me of using -path when it is great when you don't want to prune all subdirectory with the same basename :D

Comment: Exactly. '-path' is dependent from basedir. Here are two examples  exclude the same folder. Pls notice how '-path' changes when you change basedir. 1)  find '/home/vasya' -path '/home/vasya/.git' -prune  -o -name "*.txt" -print  2) find '.' -path './.git' -prune  -o -name "*.txt" -print

Answer (score 3):

`find` builds a list of files. It applies the predicate you supplied to each one and returns those that pass.

This idea that `-prune` means exclude from results was really confusing for me. You can exclude a file without prune:

```
find -name 'bad_guy' -o -name 'good_guy' -print  // good_guy
```

All `-prune` does is alter the behavior of the search. If the current match is a directory, it says *"hey `find`, that file you just matched, dont descend into it"*. It just removes that tree (but not the file itself) from the list of files to search.

It should be named `-dont-descend`.

Answer (score 2):

Prune is a "do not recurse at this file" switch (action).

From the man page

> If -depth is not given, true;
> if the file is a directory, do not descend into it.
> If -depth is given, false; no effect.

Basically it will not descend into any sub directories.

**Take this example:**

You have the following directories:

```sh
% find home
home
home/test1
home/test1/test1
home/test2
home/test2/test2
```

`find home -name test2` will print both the parent and the child directories named **test2**:

```sh
% find home -name test2
home/test2
home/test2/test2
```

Now, with **-prune**...

`find home -name test2 -prune` will print only **/home/test2**; it will not descend into **/home/test2** to find **/home/test2/test2**:

```sh
% find home -name test2 -prune
home/test2
```

Comment: not 100% true: it is "do pruning when matching condition, and if it's a directory, take it out of the to-do list, ie don't enter it as well". -prune also works on files.

Answer (score 2):

Show everything including dir itself but not its long boring contents:

```
find . -print -name dir -prune
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read all the good answers here my understanding now is that the following all return the same results:

```
find . -path ./dir1\*  -prune -o -print

find . -path ./dir1  -prune -o -print

find . -path ./dir1\*  -o -print
#look no prune at all!
```

**But** the last one will take a lot longer as it still searches out everything in dir1.  I guess the real question is how to `-or` out unwanted results without actually searching them.

So I guess prune means don't decent past matches but mark it as done...

http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html
"This however is not due to the effect of the ‘-prune’ action (which only prevents further descent, it doesn't make sure we ignore that item). Instead, this effect is due to the use of ‘-o’. Since the left hand side of the “or” condition has succeeded for ./src/emacs, it is not necessary to evaluate the right-hand-side (‘-print’) at all for this particular file."

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few answers; some of them are a bit too much theory-heavy. I'll leave **why I needed prune** once so maybe the **need-first/example** kind of explanation is useful to someone :)

#### Problem

I had a folder with about 20 node directories, each having its `node_modules` directory as expected.

Once you get into any project, you see each `../node_modules/module`. But you know how it is. Almost every module has dependencies, so what you are looking at is more like `projectN/node_modules/moduleX/node_modules/moduleZ...`

I didn't want to drown with a list with the dependency of the dependency of...

Knowing `-d n` / `-depth n`, it wouldn't have helped me, as the main/first node_modules directory I wanted of each project was at a different depth, like this:

```
Projects/MysuperProjectName/project/node_modules/...
Projects/Whatshisname/version3/project/node_modules/...
Projects/project/node_modules/...
Projects/MysuperProjectName/testProject/november2015Copy/project/node_modules/...
[...]
```

How can I get the first a list of paths ending at the first `node_modules` and move to the next project to get the same?

#### Enter `-prune`

When you add `-prune`, you'll still have a standard recursive search. Each "path" is analyzed, and every find gets spit out and `find` keeps digging down like a good chap. But it's the digging down for more `node_modules` what I didn't want.

So, the difference is that in any of those different paths, `-prune` will `find` to stop digging further down that particular avenue when it has found your item. In my case, the `node_modules` folder.