# What does -prune option in find do?

Tags: linux, find

I can see the -prune of `find` not working correctly. I guess `-name "efence*" -prune` option should select (or find) all files except the one with name `efence*` right?

Or am i wrong in my understanding?

The command i executed:
 `find * -maxdepth 0 -name "efence*" -prune`

**Expectation**: Select all files at current directory (`maxdepth 0`) except one with name *efence.

Please help me to understand `-prune`

Comment: I bet you'd get a better answer on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: How can i migrate? Or let the admins migrate?

Comment: Yes, it will be migrated by admins.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use '-prune' option of 'find' in sh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh)

Comment: For people who downvoted..let me tell you find can also be used on shell scripts, and shell scripts are programs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -name "efence*" -prune -o -print
```

The `prune` option *does* print matching files, if no other options are specified (it still prevents `find` from recursing into matching directories, however).

Edited to add explanation:

`find` expressions distinguish between `tests` and `actions`. From `man find`:

> The  expression  is  made up of options (which affect overall operation
>   rather than the processing of a specific file, and always return true),
>   tests  (which  return  a  true or false value), and actions (which have
>   side effects and return a true or false value), all separated by operators.  `-and` is assumed where the operator is omitted.
>
> **If the expression contains no actions other than `-prune`, `-print` is performed on all files for which the expression is true.** [my emphasis]

So `-prune` is an action which has the side effect that `find` will not recurse into subdirectories which match the preceding test (in your case, `-maxdepth 0 -name "efence*"`). But in terms of the truth-value of the expression, it's equivalent to just having

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -name "efence*" -true
```

and since you didn't specify any other action, `-print` is assumed (this assumption is always present as it allows you to type e.g. `find . -name "*.java"` instead of `find . -name "*.java" -print`).

Hope that makes sense. The accepted answer at [the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh) talks about the same thing.

Comment: I am accepting your answer, but please explain me how does `-o print` does the magic.

Comment: For the sake of completion, as a response to kingmasher1's question in comment.  What OpenSauce explains is that `find * -maxdepth 0 -name "efence*"`, `find * -maxdepth 0 -name "efence*" -prune`, `find * -maxdepth 0 -name "efence*" -prune -print` yield the same as `find * -maxdepth 0 -name "efence* -true" where `-print` is implied and the test `-true` ... always evaluates to "true".  I.e. with that instruction, you find all files whose names match the pattern `"efence*"`. Here there is no alternative action to pruning so `find ..... -prune` actually prints what it would normally prune.

Comment: _[continued from above]_ The alternative to pruning comes as the `-o -print` action in `find * -maxdepth 0 -name "efence*" -prune -o -print`. In that case the section `find * (....) -prune` actually prunes results when the test(s) `(...)` evaluate(s) to "true" and prints it when it does not. You will find that the combination of `find * (...) - prune -o -print` is  a common "conditional print pattern" (my terminology) when you use `find`.