# How can this `find -prune`'s behavior be understood?

Tags: bash, find

According to the manpage of GNU `find`, `-print` action is used by default and

> Actions which inhibit the default `-print` are `-delete`, `-exec`, `-execdir`, `-ok`, `-okdir`, `-fls`, `-fprint`, `-fprintf`, `-ls`, `-print` and `-printf`.

So `-prune` action should still imply `-print` action.

Actually, it does.

```
$ tree .
.
├── dir/
│   └── file2
└── file1

$ find . -name dir #0
./dir

$ find . -name dir -prune #1
./dir #printed as expected

$ find . -name dir -prune -or -name file1 #2
./file1
./dir #printed as expected
```

However, sometimes `-prune` inhibits the default `-print`.

```
$ find . -name dir -prune -or -name file1 -print #3 #last -print is only added to the above example
./file1

$ find . -name dir -prune -or -print #4
.
./file1
```

How can I understand this contradiction?

---

**My Understanding**:

`#1`

1. `file1` doesn't satify `-name dir` so skipped.
2. `dir` satisfies `-name dir` so pruned and `dir` is added to TODO list.
3. `-print` is additionally applied to `dir` in TODO list.

`#2`

1. `file1` satisfies `-name file1` so added to TODO list.
2. same as `#1`-2
3. `-print` is additionally applied to `dir` and `file1` in TODO list.

`#3`

1. same as `#2`-1
2. same as `#2`-2
3. `-print` is applied to `file1` in TODO list.
4. `-print` **should** additionally be applied to `dir` because `-prune` doesn't inhibit `-print`. (But this is incorrect. WHY?)

`#4`

1. `file1` is added to TODO list.
2. same as `#3`-2
3. same as `#3`-3
4. same as `#3`-4

(Actually there is no TODO list in `find`. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542440/how-can-this-find-prunes-behavior-be-understood#comment103407914_58542440) and [the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).)

---

**Supplement**:

As pointed out in [oguz ismail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58542801/8776746) (deleted now), my question is not related to `-prune`. However, the question is not solved.

Let us think about `-name A -o -name B -print`. This is broken into two expressions: `-name A` or `-name B -print`.

My understanding: The first expression `-name A` doesn't have an action. So `-print` should be implied. In other words, `-name A -o -name B -print` should be interpreted as `-name A -print -o -name B -print`.

Actual behavior: `-name A -o -name B -print` is one compound expression. There is `-print` in this compound expression. So no additional `-print` should be implied.

There is ambiguity but I believe my interpretation is more natural because, in this case, only `-name A` or `-name B -print` is satisfied by each file (both expressions are never satisfied at the same time)

Comment: You might want to look at [How to use '-prune' option of 'find' in sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1489277/5291015) and [What does -prune option in find do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6896564/5291015)

Comment: There is no such thing as TODO list in find, if an entry makes it to -print, it's printed; that's all. The expression is evaluated separately for every single entry

Comment: @oguzismail I don't think whether TODO list really exists is essential.

Comment: Wrt your last edit, POSIX mandates such behavior; so this is not a question but a suggestion to standard maintainers. At first it was a question, and it's answered

Comment: It is, misuse of terminology leads to misapprehensions. Like, the word *action* is never used in POSIX find specification, but GNU's misuse of that word led you to this confusion

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html Read the document as a whole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542440/how-can-this-find-prunes-behavior-be-understood#comment103409223_58542440) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542440/how-can-this-find-prunes-behavior-be-understood#comment103409256_58542440), my question, which is summarized in the **Supplement** section in OP, has come from the ambiguity in manpage of GNU `find` and POSIX has a better explanation. I found this is true.

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) says

> (If no expression is present, `-print` shall be used as the expression. Otherwise,) if the given expression does not contain any of the primaries `-exec`, `-ok`, or `-print`, the given expression shall be effectively replaced by:
>
> `( given_expression ) -print`

and it is natural to interpret `given_expression` is a compound expression which consists of one or more sub-expressions because it is closed in parenthesis. (If this `given_expression` referred to a single sub-expression, the parenthesis would definitely be redundant.)