# find command: list every directory and subdir, except .git or .hg dir and subdirs

Tags: bash, command, find, subdirectory

I tried to use this command in my work dir

```
find . -type d  \( ! -name .git  -prune \) -o \( ! -name .hg  -prune \)
```

Does not seem to work?

removing prune will only exclude `.git` or `.hg` directories, not their subdir

Comment: @pktangyue unfortunately I don't have rights to install `tree`

Comment: Why do you need permissions? You can install it in your home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is essentially the same as @Barmar's, which I have upvoted:

`find . \( -name .git -o -name .hg \) -prune -o \( -type d -print \)`

A little explanation about this command might be helpful to you:

Here `-o` means `OR`. When `find` finds a file's name matching `.git` or `.hg`, it stops the further search due to `-prune` option and evaluates to `true`, hence skips the other `-o` branch(which is directory printing). That's why only those directories not containing `.git` or `.hg` will show up.

You may also refer to this question on SO: [How to use '-prune' option of 'find' in sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh)

Answer (score 4):

```
find . \( -name .git -o -name .hg \) -prune -o -type d -print
```