# how to correctly use prune? -type d and -type f have a different effect on prune?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, find, gnu

When I use

```
find . -type f -path ./source/script -prune -o -print;
```

I get files in the "pruned" ./source/script directory.

```
...
./source/script
./source/script/myapp02.4372d2ea3388.js
./source/script/myapp02.js
./source/script/myapp02.1798d7bc34d2.js
...
```

But when I use:

```
find . -path ./source/script -prune -o -type f -print;
```

the files in the "pruned" directory are omitted:

```
./generate.py
./readme.txt
./source/class/myapp02/Application.js
./source/class/myapp02/Application.js:75:      
./source/class/myapp02/__init__.js
./source/class/myapp02/Application.js~
./source/class/myapp02/theme/Font.js
./source/class/myapp02/theme/Theme.js
./source/class/myapp02/theme/Decoration.js
./source/class/myapp02/theme/Color.js
./source/class/myapp02/theme/Appearance.js
./source/class/myapp02/simulation/DemoSimulation.js
./source/class/myapp02/test/DemoTest.js
./source/translation/readme.txt
./source/index.html
./source/index.html~
./source/resource/myapp02/test.png
./Manifest.json
./config.json
```

In [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command) I see:

```
find . -type d \( -path dir1 -o -path dir2 -o -path dir3 \) -prune -o -print
```

The only difference I see with mine is that the `-type d` is in my code `-type f`.

Is that the only reason why `-prune` is ignored and the find program searches inside the "pruned" directory?

Comment: This has some good examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -type f -path ./source/script -prune -o -print;
```

is interpreted as

```
find . (-type f AND -path ./source/script AND -prune) OR (-print);
```

---

```
find . -path ./source/script -prune -o -type f -print;
```

is interpretted as

```
find . (-path ./source/script AND -prune) OR (-type f AND -print);
```

---

*Note that `-print` and `-prune` are expressions that evaluate to **true**.*

So if `(-path ./source/script AND -prune)` is **true** then `(-type f AND -print)` is not evaluated and `-print` is not called. And `` `(-path ./source/script AND -prune) `` is true for all the files and subdirectories of `./source/script`