# Why doesn't the argument -type d take effect in find command?

Tags: linux, shell

I used

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 \( -path ./.repo -o -path ./out -o -path ./release \) -prune -type d -o -print
.
./external
./anno
./system
./cts
./bionic
./sdk
./abi
./build
./kernel
./hardware
./prebuilts
./MAKE_SUCCESS_FILE
./buildlog
./docs
./prebuilt
./libnativehelper
./bootable
./dalvik
./vendor
./make-export-env
./rawprogram0.xml.bak
./development
./libcore
./device
./frameworks
./pdk
./ndk
./packages
./Makefile
./gdk
```

to find only folders except .repo out and release in current directory, but the result contains non-folder files, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of your command doesn't mean what you think it does. In particular, `-prune` doesn't exclude the identified files, it just prevents them from being descended into (which in your case is already guaranteed by the `-maxdepth 1` anyway), and `-o` means "or" (a short-circuiting Boolean OR), so you're actually applying `-print` to the files that *don't* satisfy your test.

I think what you want is this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name .repo -not -name out -not -name release -type d
```

which prints `.`, plus all directories in `.` aside from `./.repo`, `./out`, and `./release`.

Answer (score 0):

The things you want to prune come before -prune.
[How to use '-prune' option of 'find' in sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh)