# Unable to use "-prune" option from find command

Tags: linux

I don't want to find "passwd" under "/etc" directory, but I do want to find rest of the "passwd", I am trying following,

```
sudo find / -name '/etc' -prune -o -name 'passwd' -print
```

this is the output I get,

```
/home/previous_cache/1_0_59/httpd-2.4.7/srclib/apr/passwd
/home/1_0_59/httpd-2.4.7/srclib/apr/passwd
/etc/pam.d/passwd
/etc/passwd
/etc/cron.daily/passwd
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/passwd
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/passwd
/usr/share/doc/passwd
/usr/bin/passwd
```

this is the output I expect,

```
/home/previous_cache/1_0_59/httpd-2.4.7/srclib/apr/passwd
/home/1_0_59/httpd-2.4.7/srclib/apr/passwd
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/passwd
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/passwd
/usr/share/doc/passwd
/usr/bin/passwd
```

[I referred this, good info about prune, but could not solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 find / -path '/etc' -prune -o -name 'passwd' -print
```

Answer (score 0):

try -path instead of -name

```
sudo find / -path /etc -prune -o -name 'passwd' -print
```