# Pruning all sub directories in the current directory

Tags: bash, find

tried to print all the files in the current directory using

```
find .  -newer myfile -mtime +3 ! -name . -prune
```

but it is also printing the files in the sub directories 
tried to read related post here :

[How to use '-prune' option of 'find' in sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh)

but did not understand but tried

```
find . -newer myfile -mtime +3 ! -name . -prune -o -print
```

this also did not bring what I wanted 
also tried

```
find . -type f  -newer myfile -mtime +3 ! -name . -prune
```

but this is bringing all .snapshots sub directories in the output recursively. 
Please tell me how can I avoid all sub directories in the out put using prune.

OUTPUT

```
find .  -newer myfile -mtime +3 ! -name . -prune

./.snapshot/hourly.7/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/hourly.1/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/hourly.6/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/hourly.5/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/nightly.0/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/hourly.0/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/hourly.4/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/hourly.2/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/hourly.3/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/nightly.2/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/nightly.1/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/veritas.nfs01p_vol1/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/weekly.0/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/lonnf30060(1874649454)_nfs01p_vol1.58917/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/lonnf30060(1874649454)_nfs01p_vol1.58916/file_status_out.txt
./.snapshot/dfpm_base(dataset-id-225039)conn1.0/file_status_out.txt
./file_status_out.txt
```

Comment: I dont get you. What are you trying to accomplish? If you do not want find files in subdirectories just add "-maxdepth 1" flag.

Comment: I have edited so that it makes more sense , with my actual purpose

Comment: Please list some example files (name and relative path) and wether you want them to be found or not and why.

Comment: Please, explain what you intend to achieve with the `!´.

Comment: I want to find out all the files that are newer than myfile() but older than 3 days in the current directory (not in any of the sub directories)

Comment: I have shown the output of my command , I cannot understand why the command is descending to .snapshot directories even if all the subdirectories are pruned in the command

Comment: As Martias says.....just use -maxdepth 1

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -newer myfile -mtime +3 ! -name . -prune | xargs ls -l`
find: bad option -maxdepth seems like maxdepth is not supported on my unix  `uname -v`
Generic_118833-36

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the last modification time of "myfile", implicitly find does a `-and` or `-a` with the expressions, so the paths to prune are (directory files) newer than myfile `-newer myfile` and `-mtime +3` with last modification time greater than 3 days, this may be not possible if myfile is more recent than 3 days.

Another solution to prune directories if `-maxdepth` is not supported

```
find . ! -name . -type d -prune -o -print
```

specific condition can be added after `-o`

```
find . ! -name . -type d -prune -o -newer myfile -print
```

update following comments, it seems conditions are not added at the right place:

```
find . ! -name . -type d -prune -o -newer myfile -mtime +1 -print
```

conditions before `-prune` are to filter subdirectories (type d except . otherwise would return nothing), conditions after `-o` are to filter files to `-print` or to `-ls` depending the last argument

Comment: details of myfile is `-rw-------   1 xxxx  xxxx       0 Sep 29 00:00 myfile` command you have given `find . ! -name . -type d -prune -o -newer myfile -print` also bring file which are not older than 3 days as it prints files modified today and yesterday. I also did not understand why you have used `-o` for OR I want to print file that satisfy `-and`. Things become worst when I do `find . ! -name . -type d -prune -o -newer myfile -print | xargs ls -l` as this seems to long list everything

Comment: `-o` is needed after `-prune` to bypass false for files not pruned

Comment: your comments confirm my answer `-mtime +3` and `-newer myfile` can't be true because Sep 29 was exactly 3 days before now

Comment: it still prints those snapshots if I make it `mtime +1` in that command

Comment: where did you add -mtime +1

Comment: `find .  -newer myfile -mtime +1 ! -name . -prune`

Comment: this looks better I did `find . ! -name . -type d -prune -o -newer myfile -mtime +1 -print | xargs ls -l` which brings output `  `-rw-------   1 xxxx  xxxx   22564 Sep 29 22:16 ./.bash_history
-rw-------   1 xxxx  xxxx       0 Sep 29 14:11 ./file_status_out.txt
-rw-------   1 xxxx  xxxx     922 Sep 29 18:10 ./filefile.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1 xxxx  xxxx    1409 Sep 29 18:10 ./formatperl.pl
-rwx------   1 xxxx  xxxx    1408 Sep 29 18:17 ./formatperl2.pl
-rwx------   1 xxxx  xxxx    1402 Sep 29 18:22 ./formatperl3.pl
-rw-------   1 xxxx  xxxx       0 Oct  1 00:00 ./myfile1`

Comment: I guess bu default it will aslo match hidden files so `./.bash_history` is in the out put and also it does not print file of Oct 2 `-rw-------   1 xxxx  xxxx 1354656 Oct  2 12:20 jobs2
-rwxrwxrwx   1 xxxx  xxxx     396 Oct  2 14:34 perlfor.pl` command ran as of `Tue Oct  3 15:46:35 BST 2017`