# Cannot delete files that are present in a directory sharing same prefix name

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a function and I want to delete the files in a directory.
It does the desired work, like if i want to delete from `abc/xyz/p.txt` Then it will delete `p.txt`.
But if I want to delete `abc/xyz/x.txt` then It does not delete `x.txt` because the name starts with `x` and the directory it resides is also starting with `x`.

Below is the code-

```
fn_DeleteFiles()
{
set -x
    fn_Log ${INFO} "Deleting the files older the Retention Period days"
    if [ 0 -eq `find ${FILE_DIR} -mtime +${RETENTION_DAYS} -type f -name "${FILE_NAME_PREFIX}*" | wc -l` ]
    then
        fn_Log ${INFO} "There are no files in the file directory older than ${RETENTION_DAYS} days."
    else
        # Deleting the files older than Purge days and Invoke fn_Log() function to log the file name in the log file
        find ${FILE_DIR} -prune -name "${FILE_NAME_PREFIX}*" -type f -mtime +${RETENTION_DAYS} | while read NAME; do echo ${NAME};rm -f ${NAME};
        fn_Log ${INFO} "Deleting file: ${NAME} " ;
        done
        if [ ${?} -ne 0 ]
        then
            fn_Log ${ERROR} "Purging of files in the file Directory ${FILE_DIR} has not completed successfully."
        else
            fn_Log ${INFO} "Purging of files in the file Directory ${FILE_DIR} completed successful"
        fi
    fi
}
```

Comment: Your example code is complicated and incomplete. What is `FILE_DIR`? what is `FILE_NAME_PREFIX`?

Answer (score 0):

From `find` man page:

`-prune True; if the file is a directory, do not descend into it.`

Now, if you make `FILE_NAME_PREFIX='x'` then `find` will not process `xyz` because it matches `${FILE_NAME_PREFIX}*`.

so, `-prune` is overriding your `-type f` default action which is `-print`. Try removing `prune`since you already instructed to find files only.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh) has more info.

Comment: but i need prune command to not to descend into sub directory...is there any other way?

Comment: In that case replace `prune` with `-maxdepth 0`.

Comment: Hi @luis maxdepth cannot be used in few UNIX versions, mine happens to be one of them.

Comment: What's your version and your OS? try `find --version`.