# Too slow ember-cli build on windows

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have just started to play with Ember and ember-cli. I created a template project and added very few lines of js and some sass files from Web Starter Kit. And my project incremental build times are almost 15 to 25 seconds. I am running Windows 8.1, SSD , i5 with 12 GB RAM.

```
C:\Users\MyUser\Projects\ember\webapp>ember --version
version: 0.1.4
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events
node: 0.10.29
npm: 2.1.10
```

Project source: https://github.com/mmrath/ember-webapp

I have tried excluding the project directory from indexing, windows defender and excluding node from windows defender. Nothing worked so far.

How can I bring down the build time?

UPDATE: After running command prompt as admin

```
C:\Users\MyUser\ember\webapp>ember serve
version: 0.1.4
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events
Livereload server on port 35729
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200/

Build successful - 5632ms.

Slowest Trees                  | Total
-------------------------------+----------------
SassCompiler                   | 713ms
EsnextFilter                   | 622ms
ES6Concatenator                | 530ms
EsnextFilter                   | 413ms
Funnel                         | 374ms
TreeMerger (vendor)            | 343ms
TreeMerger (appAndDependencies) | 321ms

file added styles\wsk\components\_components\_sidebar-menu.scss

Build successful - 7171ms.

Slowest Trees                  | Total
-------------------------------+----------------
TreeMerger (vendor)            | 879ms
SassCompiler                   | 745ms
Funnel                         | 667ms
TreeMerger (appAndDependencies) | 467ms

file changed styles\wsk\components\components.scss
file changed styles\app.scss
file changed styles\wsk\components\_components\_sidebar-menu.scss

Build successful - 5707ms.

Slowest Trees                  | Total
-------------------------------+----------------
Funnel                         | 1119ms
TreeMerger (vendor)            | 656ms
SassCompiler                   | 586ms
TreeMerger (appAndDependencies) | 389ms
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a common problem. See [discuss.emberjs.com](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-cli-rebuild-alternative-on-windows-due-to-slowness/6299/2) and [GitHub](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2680) for discussion and further tweaks you could try.

Comment: I ran cmd as administrator and it does cut down a lot of ms. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for symlinks to work, I believe you need to run the console as administrator. I just cloned your app, and did an incremental build test with two versions of console running.

The version of console not run as administrator took 8 seconds for initial build, and 8 seconds for incremental.

The version of console run as administrator took 8 seconds for initial build, and 800ms for incremental build.

EDIT: For those finding this through searches, take a look at an Ember addon to automatically configure your environment. Also available as a standalone npm package for those not wanting to install as an addon.

https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-cli-windows-addon
https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-cli-windows

Comment: I tried this. Around 8-10 seconds for initial build and around 5 seconds for incremental build. Though I still want it to be lesser, this is much better than what I had. Thanks @Mike1o1

Comment: Can you post what the output of your incremental build is? Do you have any backup service running, perhaps? I had issues with Crash Plan slowing my builds and I had to add my project folders to the exclude list.