# How to speed up the Angular build process

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After making some changes in my TypeScript files, each build takes over 20 minutes.
I run this command: `ng build --output-path=..\..\static\angularjs`.

If I run it in Microsoft PowerShell, it needs 25 - 30 seconds. This is a lot of time.

**Enviroment**

- Windows 10
- 8 GB-Ram
- PyCharm 64
- MS PowerShell

How can I speed this up?

Comment: Does `ng build` emit any output? Does it give you an indication of which steps are slow?

Comment: the `output-path` is an alternative to the `dist` directory. there are no other indicators.

Comment: http://dotnet--solutions.blogspot.com/2020/09/i-am-using-angular-cli-7-and-i-am-going.html

Comment: maybe wsl2 hepls https://stackoverflow.com/a/66481419/1359764

Comment: WSL 2 cross-file system access is very slow. Better having the app source on the native WSL 2 Linux file system, this is much, much faster.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

My app took 28secs to build, but I've reduced the time to 9secs. Usings this flag

```
ng build --source-map=false
```

you can see the difference in time comparing the time:

```
ng build --stats-json 

ng build --stats-json --source-map=false
```

source map is intended only for debugging, Hope it helps

Comment: If you remove any way to debug the TS files , this doesn't help a developer, does it?

Comment: I'm a developer and this is extremely helpful. I don't need debug information 100% of the time (and I'll still get some errors that will be self explanatory). I expect this to save a lot of time when I'm actually *developing* new stuff. For me compile time for a full build went from 35 to 23 seconds. For an `ng serve` it went from 22 to 16 seconds.

Comment: And having used this for a couple days I'm also realizing that usually having a single file to debug in chrome (main.js) is actually often much easier than many typescript files - especially if you want to set breakpoints. The speed increase for recompilation when a small change is made - down from 2-3 seconds to about half a second. The bottleneck now is the time it takes Chrome to parse and display the page - which hopefully will be much faster with the upcoming Ivy renderer.

Comment: I have such message. The option '--source-map' is not registered with the serve command

Comment: With newer versions it is --sourcemaps=false

Comment: @АртурГудиев this was for `ng build`, not `ng serve`

Comment: Uh... Source Map is not just for debugging. It's also for being able to support production with real code references instead of minified variable names,e tc.

Comment: you dont add prod as a parameter ? prod is very important because it reduces runtime sleed cause it compresses more code and files.

Comment: Didn't help. After I enter "ng build" I get like 10-15 s of pause, and then starts "generating modules etc..." And, this second part is also same as before.

Comment: CI/CD systems can benefit from this too

Answer (score 45):

This reduced my build time to 50%

```
          "optimization": false,
          "outputHashing": "none",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "statsJson": false,
          "progress": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "buildOptimizer": false,
```

*Note:* If you're using an old Angular version (Angular 11) you can also try to add: `"extractCss": true,` and `"showCircularDependencies": false,`

Comment: The Comment sounds helpful, could you please help by explaining each option, i did look through the ng build documentation and couldn't find the explanations helpful.

Comment: @TheViralGriffin https://angular.io/cli/build see options section

Comment: @dota2pro what i meant was, for example there is one option called "extractLicenses", in the documentation it says that "extractLicenses" "Extracts all licenses in a separate file". In this scenario which licences are we talking about. Hence i suggested, if possible and if you are aware what those option do, you could brief them so that people visiting the post might find it extremely helpful.

Comment: @dota2pro where do you place this configuration options ? In the angular.json file ?

Comment: I would leave in "showCircularDependencies": true, because this be the root for terrible code

Comment: +1 This is a great answer that helped me a lot to optimize the dev build. Everyone wondering where to place and how to use those properties, along with some stats, can read my own answer below

Comment: note that 'showCircularDependencies' option deprecated and 'extractCss' removed in angular 14.

Comment: @AmirAzizkhani 11, not 14. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67209871/extracting-css-into-js-with-angular-11-deprecated-extractcss

Answer (score 23):

Based on others' answers I created my own configuration, which reduced dev build time **three times**.

1. In the `angular.json` I created a new profile called `"development"` under `projects.<my-project-name>.architect.build.configurations`:

   ```
   "development": {
     "optimization": false,
     "outputHashing": "none",
     "sourceMap": true,
     "namedChunks": false,
     "aot": true,
     "extractLicenses": false,
     "statsJson": false,
     "progress": true,
     "vendorChunk": true,
     "buildOptimizer": false
   },
   "production": {
     ...
   ```

   Here I enable source maps. If you don't need them, you can set `sourceMap` flag to `false`, it will reduce build time even more.
2. In the `package.json` file I added a new script called `watch`:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     ...
     "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development"
   }
   ```
3. Then I just have to run in the command line:

   ```
   npm run watch
   ```

   and see the build taking much less than before and also on each change it rebuilds everything even quicker.

My final stats are the following:

- Default settings: 77 sec
- With source maps: 25 sec
- Without source maps: 21 sec

Comment: I changed `aot` to `false` and it worked very very very well, 20Sec to 500miliSec

Comment: @aniranmohammadpour Thanks for the tip, need to try it too. Be careful though, because you may have different build results/errors with and without AOT. So after going through multiple dev build cycles, you still have to build it at least once with AOT turned on, as you would want it on prod

Comment: @afrish hence the reason this is a development configuration. During development you want to have a faster build/feedback cycle (as fast as possible ideally). While your CI/CD should indeed contain at least one "normal" build.

Answer (score 21):

I've found that for me, this issue was solved by using the `watch` flag, i.e.

```
ng build --watch=true
```

This runs constantly, and automatically builds files only when saved. It has dropped my build time from 8 sec to <1 sec for small changes in code, since it only generates `.js` files for what actually changed.

From https://angular.io/guide/deployment

> The `ng build` command generates output files just once and does not
>   serve them.
>
> The `ng build --watch` command will regenerate output files
>   when source files change. This `--watch` flag is useful if you're
>   building during development and are automatically re-deploying changes
>   to another server.

You should probably use `ng build` with the necessary options when you are building for production so that the necessary optimizations are completed.

Comment: I believe `watch` mode is not considered a build in this question. OP search for way to speed up overall build process for deployment, not in development.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Tomas. I added this answer because I could imagine someone else coming to this question, and this answer being just what they needed (like it was for me). 
Could you explain why you believe `watch` mode isn't considered a build? OP talked about "some changes in TypeScript Files" so I thought this would be a valuable answer.

Comment: in `watch` mode Angular will rebuild only chunks of changed code, thus it's considerably faster, however does not reflect overall production build process, when all files need to be compiled, tree-shaked and bundled. Thus disabling `watch` will speed up development process (on local development each file change can be assigned to single chunk) of each subsequent build (but not the first one), it will completely not affect production build. But yeah, `some change` as OP mentions may indicate he refer to development (not releasing/building itself) process.

Comment: Please just add a note in answer that this will affect development process build speed, not building deployment and I'll be happy to took back my down vote.

Comment: Hi @Tomas, I've improved the answer for nivlac. Do you think this better answers the question?

Comment: Thanks Stephen and Tomas! This was my first SO answer, so your feedback is very much appreciated :)

Comment: --watch is useful to test the final build and you need to make changes on the fly, but the initial build (the first time you run it) will take the same amount of time, I wouldn't recommend this as a solution.

Answer (score 11):

According to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6795 using `--build-optimizer=false` speeds up the build.

Answer (score 11):

*If this answer helps you, please leave a comment on what specific advice was helpful!*

I recently upgraded from Angular 8 to Angular 13. My **build** time was comparable (~10 minutes in both Angular 8 and Angular 13), but I struggled with my **rebuild** time (i.e. I use `--watch` while I develop; if I change only a few files, Angular 8 was recompiling in *<10 **seconds***; Angular 13 required another **10 minutes**!).

**I used `angular.json` (see below for a screenshot) to specify `"aot":false` and I saw much better *re*build times (back to ~8-10 seconds)** -- this option is the same as `angular-cli` [`ng build` command's](https://angular.io/cli/build) `--aot=false`.

I'm adding my answer because currently no other answer suggests trying to use `"aot:false`. In fact, many of the most popular answers explicitly suggest trying `"aot":true`! Those answers aren't wrong (in fact, they identify options that improve performance, like `"sourceMap":false`.) But for me, `"aot":false` was the gamechanger.

Also, I *recognize the benefits of ["AOT" (Ahead-of-Time compilation)](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)*, for example "faster rendering in the browser".  I **still use "AOT" (`"aot":true`) for my production builds**; but my answer here is focused on **development**, where I use `--watch` to re-build on file changes, so I want a fast re-build, and I don't mind "slower rendering in the browser".

Some helpful resources (I will add more if I find more):

- [This comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/40635#issuecomment-772786414) suggests AOT compilation *might be* slower than JIT compilation, which may be the reason `"aot":false` works for me
- [This comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/40635#issuecomment-833731765) might help you profile your build process (to find the bottleneck/troubleshoot long build times) using `node --inspect` and `chrome://inspect`
- [This comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/40573#issuecomment-766776662) has more tips on profiling with `NG_BUILD_PROFILING=1`

Other tips that may improve build performance:

- [This blog post](https://netbasal.com/make-your-build-faster-in-angular-v12-ca041b37946e) describes the `NG_PERSISTENT_BUILD_CACHE=1` option For Angular <=12 ([I think this option was made the default in Angular 13](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/20756#issuecomment-870346063),  [RFC here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21545)

  - In Angular 13 the `NG_PERSISTENT_BUILD_CACHE` may be related/replaced by the `angular.json` `"cache"` property, [as described here in Angular 13 release blogpost](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v13-is-now-available-cce66f7bc296#05df), and this [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#cache-options); the *default* value of `"cache": { "enabled": ...` is **true**!
- [Another Git Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20792) that talks about using a custom builder [like `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20792#issuecomment-872596822), and [`"aot":false`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20792#issuecomment-876096652)

Some related stuff (more experimental / may not be helpful) :

- Blogposts like [this one](https://how-to.dev/how-to-build-minimal-angular-12-app-with-esbuild) suggest you could use your own builder, like `esbuild`, to see build performance improvements -- but this is more experimental and may not support "native ways" of doing things in Angular (i.e. the `templateUrl` property). Also they could come *at a cost (i.e. larger bundle sizes)*
- [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-lipaiZII8&t=215s) from Google Chrome Developers talks about principles for "startup performance" , however it's >1 year old, and focuses bundle size and other best practices; so the video may *make suggestions that **decrease** build performance (for other tradeoffs like smaller bundles or easier debugging)*.

**EDIT**
I set "aot":false` in my angular.json as shown in the below screenshot. Notice the location/path in the JSON is:

`root>projects>{craft-app}>architect>build>configurations>{development}`

... where `{craft-app}` is the specific name of the angular project you need to build and `{development}` is the specific name for the configuration you want to use and specify in the `-c` argument, as in:

`ng build craft-app -c=development`

[image: screenshot of angular.json structure showing the angular.json root>projects>{craft-app}>architect>build>configurations>{development} object has aot false value]

Comment: where do you put the aot option in Angular.json

Comment: @user1034912 I added a screenshot showing where to put the aot option. If it answers your question, do you mind upvoting? Thanks

Comment: Perfect answer. This really helped me a lot. Thank you a thousand times. May god bless your life.

Answer (score 6):

This reduced my build time to 70%

```
      "optimization": false,
      "outputHashing": "none",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "showCircularDependencies": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": false,
      "statsJson": false,
      "progress": false,
      "vendorChunk": true,
      "buildOptimizer": false
```

Comment: Also try to set `aot` to false. But only during development. Be sure to keep using AOT during your production builds. Ps. `showCircularDependencies` and `extractCss` are no more.

Answer (score 3):

You can use node parameter `--max_old_space_size` like

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/ngbuild --prod --build-optimizer
```

But I prefer to set it up via environment:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096
```

It speedup our build process on CI pipeline twice.

Comment: One of the easiest and effective solutions. To set the appropriate value for max_old_space_size check official documentation https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_max_old_space_size_size_in_megabytes. E.g. 'On a machine with 2GB of memory, consider setting this to 1536 (1.5GB) to leave some memory for other uses and avoid swapping.'

Answer (score 3):

Adding an answer which might be relevant only to the more recent Angular versions (10 and later)

I discovered that the mixing `CommonJS` and `AMD` dependencies is the culprit in my case.

The angular build process issues these kinds of warnings to indicate that you are in this situation:

```
Warning: xxxxxx.ts depends on 'yyyyyy.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

My own rebuild time was unbearable at almost 6 minutes in this state - note that this is a *rebuild* - meaning it's just for saving one modified typescript file:

```
Build at: 2021-05-28T07:39:58.559Z - Hash: 5f8c96f22c3daf60faa2 - Time: 234429ms
```

But when I removed the offensive references, initial build time went down to about 80 seconds, and rebuild times went down to 7-8 seconds.

Admittedly, you might not always be able to remove references to offensive modules, but in my case I was able to do that for local debugging, and to keep them when deploying. This sped up my development considerably.

Comment: I'm using rxjs-compat first operator to be able to do .first() on an Observable (which wraps the next in a promise). Any idea if there's a non-commonjs equivalent of that? Scourged through google but no success...

Comment: @DFSFOT would `firstValueFrom` work for you? https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom

Answer (score 2):

While in dev mode you can change this flag for your development to

```
"buildOptimizer": false
```

This worked for me . Angular 7 .

Comment: --build-optimizer
    Enables '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer' optimizations when using the '**aot**' option.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all optimizations for prod build

[image]

The time decreases from one hour to 6 min in my project

Answer (score -2):

###### Close unused VS Code windows when you have too many open

If like me you tend to never close VS Code windows you'll eventually end up with hundreds of tabs. This can really slow things down, more than you might think. While you're running a slow Angular build VSCode will be running through the same files at the same time and compiling code in tabs you haven't looked at in a month.

When my laptop fans are going crazy (and my Angular build is slow), closing all VS Code tabs has very often made a huge difference.

I'd also recommend adding your work directory into exclusions for your virus checking software (provided you trust all the code).

---

Edit: Originally started with this more generic statement:

Don't forget to always keep a close eye on what else your machine is doing and monitor overall CPU usage.

Comment: This is hardly an answer. You could answer this to _any_ performance related StackOverflow thread.

Comment: Good point.. I was mining crypto accidentally in the background and also forgot to stop my cross-compiling of the Linux kernel to ARM and aarch64. And running 5 VMs in the background, plus of course might need to close my video encoding process as well maybe.

Comment: @Jeppe I 100% stand by this. However point taken, so I've reordered this question to make it less generic.