# Reduce the build time in a large Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

It is taking almost 10-15 minutes to build the project in the production mode and the dist folder size is 32MB

these are the production options that I am using:-

```
"production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
```

I am running following command to build the project:-

**node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --source-map=false --named-chunks=false --statsJson=false**

PS: I already tried with Ivy. It is not supporting legacy code hence, failing the build.

Any help will be much appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: i checked my prod config in angular.json
it looks very similar to yours. the only difference is this: 
`"budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]`

Comment: why dont you use `ng build...` ? and is `ng serve` also slow?

Comment: can you check in the dist folder which files are so big?

Comment: 10 - 15... parsecs?

Comment: @crashmstr 15-15 minutes

Comment: @spierala no ng serve is not slow. only ng build --prod is slow

Comment: @spierala main.js is of 2.5 MB

Answer (score 3):

Here are some basic steps

- Reduce the number of libraries that your app imports
- Ensure that all important libraries are in FESM/ESM format and not UMD/CommonJS format
- Reduce the amount of Sass/Less that your app imports
- Verify that you aren't importing/generating duplicate styles ([1](https://material.angular.io/guide/duplicate-theming-styles))
- Break your app up into more modules and further investigate the largest/slowest modules
- Break parts of your app out into libraries (and consider pointing your path mappings to the `dist/` version of your libs
- Reduce the size and number of assets used by your app
- Some versions of Angular or the CLI have regressions in this area, the latest 8.3.x or 11.2.x is recommended
- Reduce the number of circular module and library dependencies in your app

If you do all of this and your prod builds are still over 10 minutes, I'd suggest looking into [Nx incremental builds](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/ci/incremental-builds#incremental-builds).

If you get that all set up and your builds are still too slow and you have multiple teams working on your app, then you may want to look into [Module Federation](https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/the-microfrontend-revolution-module-federation-in-webpack-5/).

Answer (score 0):

Check the [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242553/how-to-speed-up-the-angular-build-process/56992143) answer of the Previous Questions

```
ng build --source-map=false
```

Hope this will helps... !!

Comment: thanks,I have already added that option in my following query:-
node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --source-map=false --named-chunks=false --statsJson=false

Comment: it doesn't help much

Comment: Please let me know if you have any better solution

Comment: sorry ...!! , will check and let you know...!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try webpack Bundle Analyzer to see if you have some large bundles generated...

https://alligator.io/angular/bundle-size/

Answer (score -1):

you can disable "optimization", "aot" and "buildOptimizer" for faster build.
but that may make the dist folder size even worse.

Comment: yes. thats the whole point, I would like to keep the optimization too