# Extracting CSS into JS with Angular 11 (deprecated extractCss)

Tags: angular-cli

We are using an Angular 11 app to create a web component. For this it is necessary that all styles are bundled inline into a single JS file. Before Angular 11, we used to do this with `extractCss: false` in then `angular.json` config. Now this option has been marked deprecated, and I have not found any documentation on how this should be accomplished now. NB. The `extractCss: false` still works for the moment.

Answer (score 39):

One of the changes for Angular CLI 11.0 is **deprecation** of `extractCss` configuration property.

Getting error “extractCss is deprecated” comes because it has default value as true now. `extractCss` can be safely removed from `angular.json` or during the upgrade schematics should do it for you. This means that we don’t use `styles.js` anymore during the application build. The migration schematic should remove unused properties or replace them with the new alternative once you do the upgrade.

https://angular.io/cli/build

> --extract-css
>
> Deprecated: Deprecated since version 11.0. No longer required to
> disable CSS extraction for HMR.  Extract CSS from global styles into
> '.css' files instead of '.js'.

Comment: How does this answer the question? I mean, the question was: how to build web components now, that the extractCss is deprecated?

Comment: I tried out to build and run in development and production mode, without custom webpack file. I removed "extractCss" from angular.json file and changed "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" under "styles" option to "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css". Styling works well. In development mode, there are styles.css, styles.js listed. In production mode there is styles.{hashCode}.css file generated that contains all the styles, placed in app/dist folder. With custom webpack, probably somebody else can give a good answer.

Comment: I have done the upgrade to angular 13, but I still see the style.js in prod

Answer (score 6):

Removing extractCss in angular.json solves the problem

> "extractCss": true

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem on the new Angular 13. In my case I solved it by adding styles to app.component.scss

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some more description so that it is clear what you mean by "adding styles to app.component.scss." Maybe you could give an idea of what it was and what you changed it to?

Comment: Please be more descriptive with what you exactly done

Comment: I won't down vote, but I have to agree with the above comments. I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Just add your styles to app.component.scss and disable style encapsulation