# Trying to use Git add doesn't work: Permission denied

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, windows-10

So I see there are lots of solutions to my problem. My issue is that as a git newbie, nobody seems to explain it in a way that people like myself can understand. I'm trying to use git add . and it produces this error:

```
$ git add .
error: open("fileDirectory"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file 'files'
fatal: adding files failed
```

A solution I saw that supposedly worked perfectly for other people was to have it default to run as administrator by editing the Git Bash.vbs (reference: [Unable to modify git bash Windows shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621281/unable-to-modify-git-bash-windows-shortcut) ) , but they don't explain where to go to even begin to attempt this. I just felt as if it were not very beginner friendly and left me with more questions than answers. 
Note: It wouldn't let me leave a comment to simply ask because my reputation was not high enough yet! Some help on this would be much appreciated as I would like to be able to keep good version control over my unity projects. I am using windows 10

UPDATE:
I tested the whole process of using git in a test directory with just a text file and it worked fine. The directory that isn't working is my unity project, so I'm unsure if there's something any of you unity guys have done to fix this issue?

Comment: What operating system are you using? File permissions are an operating-system concept and each OS has different rules here.

Comment: Make sure you have .git in your folder in order for it to work properly

Comment: I don't see a .git in my folder, but I have run bash -> git init ?

Comment: Have you checked the folder permissions?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use Windows and have no idea how to check it, but see https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+10+file+and+folder+permissions (which turns up a lot of stuff).

Comment: What's the output of `ls -alF . | grep fileDirectory` and `whoami` in `git-bash`?

Comment: This seems barely related to `Unity3d`