# Search for executable files using find command

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, find, find-util

What type of parameter/flag can I use with the Unix `find` command so that I search executables?

Comment: type 'man find'. I think '-executable' is the option you want.

Comment: `find -executable` ... but this does not guarantee that every file listed would actually execute

Comment: Not all implementations of `find` are created equal.  The option recommended by @sje397 and @William may not be available.  It's better to use the [accepted solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4458361/543738) shown below.

Comment: Also relevant: [How to find the executable files under a certain directory in linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/38981/how-to-find-the-executable-files-under-a-certain-directory-in-linux)

Comment: Me dislikes all proposals shown below which are based on file permissions. Argumentation: for my GNU operating system (Ubuntu) it is possible to set "x" (executable) flag for for instance ASCII text file. No mimics prevented this operation from successful completion.  It needs just small mistake/bug for multiple non-intentioned files to get x flag assigned. Therefore gniourf_gniourf' solutions is my personal favorite. It has however that drawback that for cross-compiled executables needs an emulator or target device.

Comment: @William True this only finds files that have executable permission bit set. To actually determine if some file is an executable, regardless of any permissions it might have or not have, regardless if it's a shebang shell script or compiled binary, try the `file` command i.e. `file $FILEPATH | grep -q executable` which will return true if `$FILEPATH` appears to be an executable. Neat little command although Im not sure how common it is (comes pre-installed on macOS). Make sure your `file` command is [up to date](http://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/) so that it'll properly detect most shebangs.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

On GNU versions of find you can use `-executable`:

```
find . -type f -executable -print
```

For BSD (and MacOS) versions of find, you can use `-perm` with `+` and an octal mask:

```
find . -type f -perm +111 -print
```

In this context "+" means "any of these bits are set" and 111 is the execute bits.

Note that this is not identical to the `-executable` predicate in GNU find. In particular, `-executable` tests that the file can be executed by the current user, while `-perm +111` just tests if any execute permissions are set.

Older versions of GNU find also support the `-perm +111` syntax, but as of [4.5.12](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-findutils/2013-09/msg00024.html) this syntax is no longer supported. Instead, you can use `-perm /111` to get this behavior.

Comment: Error `find: invalid mode ‘+111’` on findutils 4.5.11 4.fc20.

Comment: @sourcejedi Thanks. I was actually only talking about non-GNU versions of find (BSD, in particular) but older versions of GNU find actually did support that syntax too. In newer versions you'll have to use `/` instead of `+`. See the updated answer for more details.

Comment: Indeed, I misread your answer. Sorry for making it more complicated :).

Comment: If _symlinks_ to executable files should also be found, include the `-L` option: `find -L ...`.

Comment: It took me a while to understand the implications of "not identical to the -executable predicate" and "just tests if _any_ execute permissions are set": It means that `-perm +111` may yield _false positives_, i.e., files that the current user cannot actually execute. There's no way to emulate `-executable` by testing permissions alone, because what's needed is to _relate_ the _file's_ user and group identity to the _current user's_.

Comment: A POSIX-compliant equivalent of `find . -type f -perm +111 -print` is `find . -type f \( -perm -u=x -o -perm -g=x -o -perm -o=x \)`
(sorry for messing that one up in an earlier comment).

Comment: Perhaps a closer approximation of GNU find's `-executable` in BSD find is to use `find . -type f -perm -111` so as to find files that have the executable bit set for ALL security principals (user, group, other) - this strikes me as the typical real-world scenario. (As a bonus, it also happens to be POSIX-compliant, and can also be written as `find . -type f -perm -a=x`.)

Comment: Those finds find files with the execution bit set not executable files. setting the execute bit on a jpeg file does not make it an executable but the above find will show such instances. So if the question is to be intended strictly this answer is technically wrong, if we intend to find files with any of the execute bits set this answer is right.

Comment: @louigi600 Neither permissions nor `file` are flawless. A file that consists only of "echo hello" will be identified as ASCII text by `file`, but if the execute bit is set it *will* execute. So it isn't a matter of "strictness", but rather which not-entirely-reliable heuristic you want to use.

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves Ascii text with execution bit set is basically a script with no explicit interpreter. If it contains something your shell understands it will be interpreted.
  Hello World. this is some thash text with a lucky
  echo  in themiddle of it
  what now
make that executable and although it's ordinary text the middle line will actually do something. So is it text or script ?
Sorry the comment don't show new lines ... "echo in themiddle of it" is on a line on it's own.

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves yes that's why I use find . -type f -executable -exec file {} \; | grep -wE "executable|shared object|ELF|script|a\.out"
to that tou could add "ASCII text" and your issue would be solved and your file will only be found if it has execute permissions.

Answer (score 67):

<sup>Tip of the hat to @[gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) for clearing up a fundamental misconception.</sup>

This answer attempts to provide an **overview of the existing answers** and to discuss their **subtleties** and **relative merits** as well as to provide **background information**, especially with respect to **portability**.

Finding files that are executable can refer to **two distinct use cases**:

- **user-centric**: find files that are **executable *by the current user***.
- **file-centric**: find files that have (one or more) ***executable permission bits* set**.

Note that in *either* scenario it may make sense to **use `find -L ...`** instead of just `find ...` in order to **also find *symlinks to* executables**.

Note that the simplest file-centric case - looking for executables with the executable permissions bit set for ALL three security principals (user, group, other) - will *typically*, but *not necessarily* yield the same results as the user-centric scenario - and it's important to understand the difference.

#### User-centric (`-executable`)

- The **[accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4458361/45375) commendably recommends `-executable`, IF *GNU* `find` is available.**

  - GNU `find` comes with most *Linux* distros

    - By contrast, BSD-based platforms, including macOS, come with BSD find, which is less powerful.
  - As the scenario demands, `-executable` matches only files the *current user* can execute (there are edge cases.<sup>[1]</sup>).
- The ***BSD* `find` alternative offered by the accepted answer (`-perm +111`)** **answers a *different*, *file*-centric question** (as the answer itself states).

  - **Using just `-perm` to answer the *user*-centric question is *impossible***, because what is needed is to *relate* the *file's* user and group identity to the *current user's*, whereas `-perm` can only test the *file's* permissions.
    Using only [POSIX `find` features](http://man.cx/find), the question cannot be answered without involving external utilities.
  - Thus, **the best `-perm` can do (by itself) is an *approximation*** of `-executable`. **Perhaps a *closer* approximation than `-perm +111` is `-perm -111`**, so as to find files that have the executable bit set for ALL security principals (user, group, other) - this strikes me as the typical real-world scenario. As a bonus, it also happens to be POSIX-compliant (use `find -L` to include symlinks, see farther below for an explanation):

    ```
    find . -type f -perm -111  # or: find . -type f -perm -a=x
    ```
- **[gniourf_gniourf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23364613/45375)** provides a **true, portable equivalent of `-executable`**, using `-exec test -x {} \;`, albeit **at the expense of performance**.

  - *Combining* `-exec test -x {} \;` with `-perm +111` (i.e., files with *at least one* executable bit set) may help performance in that `exec` needn't be invoked for *every* file (the following uses the POSIX-compliant equivalent of BSD find `-perm +111` / GNU find `-perm /111`; see farther below for an explanation):

    ```
    find . -type f \( -perm -u=x -o -perm -g=x -o -perm -o=x \) -exec test -x {} \; -print
    ```

#### File-centric (`-perm`)

- To **answer *file*-centric questions**, it *is* **sufficient to use the POSIX-compliant `-perm` primary** (known as a *test* in GNU find terminology).

  - `-perm` allows you to test for *any* file permissions, not just executability.
  - Permissions are specified as either **octal** or **symbolic modes**. Octal modes are octal numbers (e.g., `111`), whereas symbolic modes are strings (e.g., `a=x`).
  - **Symbolic modes** identify the security principals as `u` (user), `g` (group) and `o` (other), or `a` to refer to all three. Permissions are expressed as `x` for executable, for instance, and assigned to principals using operators `=`, `+` and `-`; for a **full discussion, including of octal modes, see [the POSIX spec for the `chmod` utility](http://man.cx/chmod)**.
  - In the context of `find`:

    - **Prefixing a mode with `-`** (e.g., `-ug=x`) means: match files that have *all* the permissions *specified* (but matching files may have additional permissions).
    - Having **NO prefix** (e.g. `755`) means: match files that have this *full, exact* set of permissions.
    - **Caveat**: Both **GNU find and BSD find** implement an **additional, *nonstandard* prefix** with **are-ANY-of-the-specified-permission-bits-set logic**, but do so with ***incompatible syntax***:

      - BSD find: `+`
      - GNU find: `/` <sup>[2]</sup>
    - Therefore, **avoid these extensions, if your code must be *portable***.
- The examples below demonstrate portable answers to various file-centric questions.

---

**File-centric command examples**

Note:

- The following **examples are POSIX-compliant**, meaning they should work in any POSIX-compatible implementation, including GNU find and BSD find; specifically, this requires:

  - NOT using nonstandard mode prefixes `+` or `/`.
  - Using the POSIX forms of the *logical-operator primaries*:

    - `!` for NOT (GNU find and BSD find also allow `-not`); note that `\!` is used in the examples so as to protect `!` from shell history expansions
    - `-a` for AND (GNU find and BSD find also allow `-and`)
    - `-o` for OR (GNU find and BSD find also allow `-or`)
- The examples use *symbolic* modes, because they're easier to read and remember.

  - With mode prefix `-`, the `=` and `+` operators can be used interchangeably
    (e.g., `-u=x` is equivalent to `-u+x` - unless you apply `-x` later, but there's no point in doing that).
  - Use `,` to join partial modes; AND logic is implied; e.g., `-u=x,g=x` means that both the user *and* the group executable bit must be set.
  - Modes cannot *themselves* express negative matching in the sense of "match only if this bit is NOT set"; you must use a separate `-perm` expression with the NOT primary, `!`.
- Note that find's *primaries* (such as `-print`, or `-perm`; also known as *actions* and *tests* in GNU find) are *implicitly* joined with `-a` (logical AND), and that `-o` and possibly parentheses (escaped as `\(` and `\)` for the shell) are needed to implement OR logic.
- `find -L ...` instead of just `find ...` is used in order to also match *symlinks to* executables

  - `-L` instructs find to evaluate the *targets* of symlinks instead of the symlinks themselves; therefore, without `-L`, `-type f` would ignore symlinks altogether.

```sh
# Match files that have ALL executable bits set - for ALL 3 security
# principals (u (user), g (group), o (others)) and are therefore executable
# by *anyone*.
# This is the typical case, and applies to executables in _system_ locations
# (e.g., /bin) and user-installed executables in _shared_ locations
# (e.g., /usr/local/bin), for instance. 
find -L . -type f -perm -a=x  # -a=x is the same as -ugo=x

# The POSIX-compliant equivalent of `-perm +111` from the accepted answer:
# Match files that have ANY executable bit set.
# Note the need to group the permission tests using parentheses.
find -L . -type f \( -perm -u=x -o -perm -g=x -o -perm -o=x \)

# A somewhat contrived example to demonstrate the use of a multi-principial
# mode (comma-separated clauses) and negation:
# Match files that have _both_ the user and group executable bit set, while
# also _not_ having the other executable bit set.
find -L . -type f -perm -u=x,g=x  \! -perm -o=x
```

---

<sup>[1] Description of `-executable` from `man find` as of GNU find 4.4.2:</sup>

> Matches  files  which  are  executable and directories which are searchable (in a file name resolution sense).  This takes into account access
>             control lists and other permissions artefacts which the -perm test ignores.  This test makes use of the access(2) system call, and so  can  be
>             fooled  by  NFS  servers which do UID mapping (or root-squashing), since many systems implement access(2) in the client's kernel and so cannot
>             make use of the UID mapping information held on the server.  Because this test is based only on the result of the access(2) system call, there
>             is no guarantee that a file for which this test succeeds can actually be executed.

<sup>[2] GNU find versions *older than  4.5.12* also allowed prefix `+`, but this was first deprecated and eventually removed, because combining `+` with *symbolic* modes yields likely yields unexpected results due to being interpreted as an *exact* permissions mask. *If* you (a) run on a version *before* 4.5.12 *and* (b) restrict yourself to *octal* modes only, you *could* get away with using `+` with *both* GNU find and BSD find, but it's not a good idea.</sup>

Comment: Most comprehensive SO answer ever ? ;)

Comment: @andynormancx :) Well, in terms of sheer number of bullet points, I can offer [this contender](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375).

Answer (score 14):

So as to have another possibility<sup>1</sup> to find the files that are executable by the current user:

```
find . -type f -exec test -x {} \; -print
```

(the test command here is the one found in PATH, very likely `/usr/bin/test`, not the builtin).

---

<sup>1</sup> Only use this if the `-executable` flag of `find` is not available! this is subtly different from the `-perm +111` solution.

Comment: Raging downvoters, please leave a note to explain why (you think) my answer is not useful or wrong.

Comment: This works, but it pretty slow. Also, depending on the shell, you might have to wrap or escape the filename place holder, like `'{}'` or `\{\}`.

Comment: @mklement0 this will not find the commands that are executable by me like `-executable` does or like my command does.

Comment: Thanks, @gniourf_gniourf - I really had a few misconceptions there. I'm reprinting your other comment here, because I'm at least for now deleting my answer (perhaps to be resurrected, IF there's something salvageable): "`find . -type f -perm -u=x` is _not_ the equivalent of `-executable`: `-executable` matches all files that user can execute, and these include `g+x` if I'm in the proper group or `o+x`. Actually `-perm -u=x` will find lots of files that user can't execute, and miss a few that user can execute."

Comment: @IonoclastBrigham: While having to quote `{}` is a hypothetical necessity (and quoting doesn't hurt), in practice it's not necessary in POSIX-like shells and `csh`. Do you know shells where it is _is_ required?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Apart from performance, your solution is equivalent to using GNU find with  `-executable`, correct? And, if I now understand correctly, one cannot fully emulate  `-executable` by testing permissions alone, because what's needed is to _relate_ the _file's_ user and group identity to the _current user's_, correct?

Comment: @mklement0 yes, that's what I believe `:)`.

Comment: @mklement0 I use FISH, the Friendly Interactive Shell ("Finally, a command
line shell for the 90s..."). It is a POSIX-like shell. But, since orthogonality and ease of use are top goals, they break with the standard whenever they deem it is inconsistent or obtuse. In FISH, '{' and '}' are actually special operators that are used for "brace expansion". The comma-delimited list of strings are each concatenated with whatever strings are adjacent to the open and close braces. Example: `echo Hello{\ World,\ StackOverflow,ooooo\ Nurse}!` prints: `Hello World! Hello StackOverflow! Helloooooo Nurse!`.

Comment: @IonoclastBrigham: Interesting, thanks; so, in `fish`,  `{}` must indeed be escaped as either `'{}'` or `\{\}`. Note that `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` provide the same kind of brace expansion; however, they print the unquoted token `{}` _as is_ (and thus: no need for escaping), because they do NOT consider it a _valid_ brace expression (they require at least _2_ tokens, or a valid numeric sequence expression), whereas `fish`  deems `{}` a _valid_ brace expression that results in the _empty_ string.

Comment: Unfortunately, directories qualify as 'executable' because of their filemode settings, so this command (as well as the 'find' examples given earlier) include directories. Depending on your use case (e.g., try searching for all executables with the name 'java') this may be quite unusable. Not only do you get directories but you also get the title-case version (e.g., Java)  as well.

Comment: @JESii thanks for your comment, but did you overlook the `-type f` predicate?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I might have, but hard to recall at this point. I'll try to retest when I get back to that system. Pretty complicated stuff.

Comment: A decent alternative when you need to work on an annoying flavour of Unix, like Solaris...

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `-executable` test flag:

```
-executable
              Matches files which are executable  and  directories  which  are
              searchable  (in  a file name resolution sense).
```

Comment: -executable is supposedly an unknown option.

Comment: Would that be a GNU Find extension?  Since the tag is Unix, not Linux, at the least a GNU extension needs to be documented as such.

Comment: This option is not supported by the BSD find command found at least on OS X. This is a GNU extension, but might be supported by other flavors of find.

Comment: FWIW, I found this to not be on sles 10, but on sles >= 11 (got a little burned by it)

Comment: Note that this does not actually get all examples. In my case I had a file which I owned as `-rw-r-xr-x` which `-executable` does not detect

Comment: @Dezza: That can happen if the file is either owned by you or you're a member of the file's group. In that event the file is _not_ executable _by you_ and therefore `-executable` doesn't report it.

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -executable -type f
```

does not really guarantee that the file is executable it will find files with the execution bit set. If you do

```
chmod a+x image.jpg
```

the above find will think image.jpg is an executable even if it is really a jpeg image with the execution bit set.

I generally work around the issue with this:

```
find . -type f -executable -exec file {} \; | grep -wE "executable|shared object|ELF|script|a\.out|ASCII text"
```

If you want the find to actually print dome information about executable files you can do something like this:

```
find . -type f -executable -printf "%i.%D %s %m %U %G %C@ %p" 2>/dev/null |while read LINE
do
  NAME=$(awk '{print $NF}' <<< $LINE)
  file -b $NAME |grep -qEw "executable|shared object|ELF|script|a\.out|ASCII text" && echo $LINE
done
```

In the above example the file's full pathname is in the last field and must reflect where you look for it with awk "NAME=$(awk '{print $NF}' <<< $LINE)"
if the file name was elsewhere in the find output string you need to replace "NF" with the correct numerical position. If your separator is not space you also need to tell awk what your separator is.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me & thought of sharing...

```
find ./ -type f -name "*" -not -name "*.o" -exec sh -c '
    case "$(head -n 1 "$1")" in
      ?ELF*) exit 0;;
      MZ*) exit 0;;
      #!*/ocamlrun*)exit0;;
    esac
exit 1
' sh {} \; -print
```

Comment: Only some thousands of cases more, and you will have have reinvented `file`!

Comment: @tripleee +1. Cool would be this extension: `find ./ -mime application/x-sharedlib -o -mime application/x-dosexec`

Comment: @Daniel Alder, which version of find you use? I did not find option -mime in find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2

Comment: @tripleee +1. utilizing 'file' &/ 'mimetype' is good idea or discover find version that supports -mime is better, Also wondering if 'file' / 'mimetype' have option to filter and display only executable(s).

Answer (score 2):

So if you actually want to find executable file types (e.g. scripts, ELF binaries etc.. etc..) not merely files with execution **permission** then you probably want to do something more like this (where the current directory . can be replaced with whatever directory you want):

```
 gfind . -type f -exec bash -c '[[ $(file -b "'{}'") == *" executable "* ]] ' \; -print
```

Or for those of you who aren't using macports (linux users) or otherwise have gnu find installed as find you want:

```
 find . -type f -exec bash -c '[[ $(file -b "'{}'") == *" executable "* ]] ' \; -print
```

Though if you are on OS X it comes with a little utility hidden somewhere called is_exec that basically bundles up that little test for you so you can shorten the command line if you find it.    But this way is more flexible as you can easily replace the == test with the =~ test and use it to check for more complex properties like executable plain text files or whatever other info your file command returns.

---

The exact rules for quotation here are pretty opaque so I just end up working it out by trial and error but I'd love to hear the right explanation.

Comment: `find . -type f -execdir sh -c "file -b {} | grep -q executable" \; -execdir realpath {} +` let you change `realpath` to something you might want to do with the executable file. Note this won't work with _potentially_ executable file, like `.sh` empty files.

Answer (score 1):

It is SO **ridiculous** that this is not super-easy... let alone *next to impossible*.  Hands up, I defer to Apple/Spotlight...

`mdfind 'kMDItemContentType=public.unix-executable'`

At least it works!

Comment: Good to know about `mdfind` on OSX. Note that uour command reports Unix executables for the _entire system_. `mdfind -onlyin . 'kMDItemContentType=public.unix-executable'` limits results to the current directory's subtree. Minor points of interest: limiting the search to a specific directory only (without subfolders) is apparently not supported. _Symlinks_ to executable files are apparently never included.  Curiously, once `mdfind` has found a file to be executable, subsequently _removing_ the executable bit is _not_ picked up.

Comment: I think I've found bugs in how Spotlight detects / undetects executable Unix files; I've filed a bug with Apple, and also at http://www.openradar.me/20162683. I encourage you - and anyone else interested in this functionality - to also file a bug at bug at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: (Sorry for the comment flurry; hopefully, they're correct now) `mdfind -onlyin . 'kMDItemContentType=public.unix-executable'` behaves like `find . -type f -perm +111 -print` does. That is, it finds files with _any_ executable bit set, which may yield _false positives_ (though that may not be a problem in practice) - to truly only find files executable by the _current user_ using BSD find, see @gniourf_gniourf's answer. Using a `find`-based solution has the advantage that you can find _symlinks_ to executable files as well, if desired (option `-L`), which `mdfind` seemingly cannot do.

Comment: @mklement0 my answer eschewed _embellishments_ - to try and nail the point home - but yes, you would almost never use this form "ungarnished".  another option - not sure if its come up - is _good old globbing_.. `ls /Applications/**/*(*)` in your (my?) [`zsh` shell](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/workshops/zsh/file_gen/file_gen.html)

Comment: Thanks for the handy `zsh` tip - didn't know that; (seems that you can _either_ match executables (`*`) _or_ symlinks (`@`), but not both, right?). As for your original point: Let me reiterate: `find . -type f -perm +a=x` will do what your `mdfind` command does, while providing more flexibility. You can even reformulate it to be POSIX-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Well the easy answer would be: "your executable files are in the directories contained in your PATH variable" but that would not really find your executables and could miss a lot of executables anyway.

I don't know much about mac but I think "mdfind 'kMDItemContentType=public.unix-executable'" might miss stuff like interpreted scripts

If it's ok for you to find files with the executable bits set (regardless of whether they are actually executable) then it's fine to do

```
find . -type f -perm +111 -print
```

where supported the "-executable" option will make a further filter looking at acl and other permission artifacts but is technically not much different to "-pemr +111".

Maybe in the future find will support "-magic " and let you look explicitly for files with a specific magic id ... but then you would haveto specify to fine all the executable formats magic id.

I'm unaware of a technically correct easy way out on unix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the answer was in the [dmenu source code](http://git.suckless.org/dmenu/tree/stest.c): the stest utility made for that purpose.  You can compile the 'stest.c' and 'arg.h' files and it should work.  There is a man page for the usage, that I put there for convenience:

```
STEST(1)         General Commands Manual         STEST(1)

NAME
       stest - filter a list of files by properties

SYNOPSIS
       stest  [-abcdefghlpqrsuwx]  [-n  file]  [-o  file]
       [file...]

DESCRIPTION
       stest takes a list of files  and  filters  by  the
       files'  properties,  analogous  to test(1).  Files
       which pass all tests are printed to stdout. If  no
       files are given, stest reads files from stdin.

OPTIONS
       -a     Test hidden files.

       -b     Test that files are block specials.

       -c     Test that files are character specials.

       -d     Test that files are directories.

       -e     Test that files exist.

       -f     Test that files are regular files.

       -g     Test  that  files  have  their set-group-ID
              flag set.

       -h     Test that files are symbolic links.

       -l     Test the contents of a directory  given  as
              an argument.

       -n file
              Test that files are newer than file.

       -o file
              Test that files are older than file.

       -p     Test that files are named pipes.

       -q     No  files are printed, only the exit status
              is returned.

       -r     Test that files are readable.

       -s     Test that files are not empty.

       -u     Test that files have their set-user-ID flag
              set.

       -v     Invert  the  sense  of  tests, only failing
              files pass.

       -w     Test that files are writable.

       -x     Test that files are executable.

EXIT STATUS
       0      At least one file passed all tests.

       1      No files passed all tests.

       2      An error occurred.

SEE ALSO
       dmenu(1), test(1)

                        dmenu-4.6                STEST(1)
```