# find folders with executable files

Tags: bash

I wrote a script to find all folders that contain executable files. I was first seeking a oneliner command but could find one. (I especially tried to use sort -k -u).

. The script works fine but my initial question remains: Is there a oneliner command to do that?

```
#! /bin/bash
find $1 -type d | while read Path
do
X=$(ls -l "$Path" | grep '^-rwx' | wc -l)
if ((X>0))
then
    echo $Path
fi
done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458120/unix-find-search-for-executable-files There's your answer.

Comment: @HermanTorjussen: this question is about finding directories with executable files in them, a bit different from your proposed dup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using find:

```
find $1 -type f -perm /111 -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u
```

This finds all files with permission 111 (i.e. `rwx`) but then we output only the directory name. To avoid duplicates, `sort -u` is used.

As pointed out by [Paulo Almeida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081569/paulo-almeida) in the comments, this would also work:

```
find $1 -type f -perm /111 -printf "%h\n" | sort -u
```

Comment: The -perm +nnn form is deprecated, prefer /111 instead.

Comment: You can also use something like `-printf "%h\n"` to avoid having to call `dirname`.

Comment: Thanks, edited my answer. I assume this solution would be faster since `dirname` calls a subprocess?