# Counting number of executable files in every variable inside PATH

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to write a script that would count number of executable files in every folder in variable PATH. My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=":"
for directory in $PATH; do
        files=0
        ls -l $directory | while read rights x name group siz m d h name; do
                if [ `echo $rights | cut -c1` = "-" ]; then
                        files=$((${files}+1))
                fi
        done
        echo "Directory ${directory} contains ${files} executable files"
done
```

I want the echo to process after the end of the while loop and before the start of next for loop, but it always print out number of files = 0. The counting inside the if condition works.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: This can be one line of php, but as usual i will be downvoted by noobs. php is better than bash itself for bash scripts... in every aspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the find command? See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458120/unix-find-search-for-executable-files). On GNU-based versions of find, something like the following should replace your ls call and while loop.

```
find $directory -type f -executable -print | wc -l
```

If you are worried about traversing subdirectories, you can use the maxdepth flag, i.e.

```
find $directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -print | wc -l
```

For BSD-versions, again, see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458120/unix-find-search-for-executable-files).

Comment: Piping the output of `find -print` to `wc` is no better than using the output of `ls`.