# Eliminating "permission denied" when /dev/null also gives 'permission denied'

Tags: linux, bash, unix, permissions

I am new to *nix and I am trying to find some files that I know are supposed to be somewhere on the system, but I am not sure where they might be or if they were even ever copied over from another project.

I was getting way too many “permission denied” messages to make sense of when using find. I searched and found this [How can I exclude all “permission denied”-messages from “find .”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find/762360#762360) , but now I have a new problem.

```
find / -name trim*  -print 2>/dev/nul
```

gives me

```
bash: /dev/nul: Permission denied
```

I searched a bit for someone with a similar issue, but I couldn't find one amid all the posts talking about  2>/dev/nul as a solution to the “permission denied”-messages

Comment: You misspelled `null`, it has two `l`s.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about misspelling `/dev/null` as `/dev/nul` and not expecting error messages.

Comment: Sorry about the silly question then.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar said, you spell `nul` instead of `null`

```
find / -name trim*  -print 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: ...and since /dev/nul doesn't exist, the shell tries to create it, and that's what gives the permissions error.