# Permission denied in find: why do we need 2>&1?

Tags: bash, error-handling, find, io-redirection

I was recently searching for a way to filter out '*Permission denied*' errors while searching for a file using the `find` command, and I found this link:

[How can I exclude all "permission denied" messages from "find"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find)

Here's an the answer that worked for me from the link:

```
find . -name "filename" 2>&1 | grep -v 'permission denied'
```

Although this answer works, I don't fully understand why we need the `2>&1` (redirection  of stderr to stdout).

Doesn't the output from the command `find . -name "filename" | grep -v 'Permission denied'` already redirect to stdout?

Comment: just dump `stderr` to `/dev/null`. no need to pipe to grep.

Comment: It is enormously important to understand that pruning the error messages will *not* make find succeed. In other words, even if you `2>/dev/null`, your find will still fail (set a non-zero exit code). This is particularly painful when there is `set -e` in the script that uses find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `'permission denied'` message is printed in stderr not stdout.

`1` is stdout

`2` is stderr

`&` specifies that whatever following is a file descriptor not filename

`2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout` and enables the error message to be piped into the `grep` command.

If excluding `permission denied` message is all you need, then this will do it without using `grep`:

```
find . -name "filename" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: But if it's printed to stderr, why do I see "find . '/path/to/file : Permission denied' " each time? It seems like it's printing to stdout in this case...

Comment: @wizurd Nope, terminal prints both stderr (in case error) and stdout (in case normal operation)...

Comment: btw, a better solution than `2>/dev/null` is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25234419/1034042)

Answer (score 1):

When using pipes you should keep in mind that only the standard output is sent to the input of the other command, that's why you need to redirect the stderr to the stdout and then send the stdout (2>&1).

```
 $ grep -v "permission denied"
```

will show the lines that do NOT contain "permission denied".
this solution works but it's far from optimal.

whenever you want to get rid of the error you shoud send it to /dev/null:

```
$ command 2> /dev/null
```

/dev/null is like a blackhole, anything you send there will just be lost.
another use of /dev/null is truncating files(for learning only, there is adequate functions to do that properly) :

```
   $ cat /dev/null > file
```

the file will be empty after issuing this command.
you should also note that the first thing the bash do is interpreting redirections for example :

```
    $ > foobar
```

will create a file foobar

let's say we want to send the stdout and the stderr of one command to a file:

```
$ command > file 2>&1
```

or

```
        $ command &> file
```

in the first example, the bash will : 
1/redirect the stderr to the stdout
2/ redirect the stdout to file
3/execute command
and that's why :

```
    $ command 2>&1 >file
```

won't work as expected.

Sometimes you will want to send the stdout to output.txt and stderr to error.txt :

```
    $ command > ouput.txt 2> error.txt
```