# updating trouble in OSX

Tags: macos, gcc

when I update my gcc in my macbook
it occurs:
  org.macports.extract for port llvm-3.5 returned: Failed to locate 'xz' in path: '/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin' or at its MacPorts configuration time location, did you move it?

but actually I don't move anything because I am a newbie,when it downloads from macport ,for too slow network speed I press some return button and it seems to have this situation that download for llvm-3.5 is failed,but it seems that I can't redownload it.

what can I do to solve this and get my gcc updating?Thanks for telling me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the file "`xz`" exists on your Mac or it doesn't.

To see if it exists, type this into the command line:

```
( find / -name xz -print > /dev/tty ) > & /dev/null
```

And what that does is that it scans your entire hard disk for a file named exactly "`xz`", [piping any errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find) (i.e. files that can be read because of permission issues) away and leaving you with the path to "xz".

If "`xz`" exists, [you can add the path to your .tcshrc file](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31442&seqNum=2), or if it doesn't exist, you need to get it.

Comment: ok I solve it by sudo port install xz. Thanks for your submission