# Linux find command permission denied

Tags: shell, find

I want to filter out the unnecessary information "Permission denied".
these are outputs from command "`find -type f -name sources.list`"

```
find: './run/lxcfs': Permission denied
find: './run/sudo': Permission denied
find: './run/lvm': Permission denied
find: './tmp/systemd-private-99eef94819d84080adc7df3e60efee5b-systemd-timesyncd.service-HE48k9': Permission denied
find: './lost+found': Permission denied
find: './dev/vboxusb': Permission denied
find: './root': Permission denied
./etc/apt/sources.list
find: './etc/sudoers.d': Permission denied
```

I tried to use "`! -readable -prune`" in conjunction with the `find` command as above to suppress the "Permission denied" information, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I exclude all "permission denied" messages from "find"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find)

Answer (score 6):

try the following

```
find -type f -name sources.list 2>/dev/null
```

This will redirect `stderr` output stream, which is used to report all errors, including the "Access denied" one, to null device.

Comment: Thank you so much, in stead of redirect the stream, is it possible to bypass those folders that i don't have read permission ?

Comment: Not sure, but, afaik, no !

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work

```
find -type d ! -readable -prune -o -type f -name sources.list
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
find / -mount -readable -name "<whatever>" -print
```

Here I only wanted to search the root file system, and not descent into any of the mounted file systems. Hence -mount.

The problem files that were throwing errors were not readable (yielding "permission denied"). Hence -readable.

The rest is obvious.

(Note: In Ubuntu 16.04 the files in /var/lib/lxcfs are not readable, even for root. The above solved the problem for me.)

Answer (score -1):

First you can check the ACL of folders with the help of

```
getfacl -R /foldername
```

if read permission is there to particular folder,then run;

```
find foldername -type f -name sources.list
```

else
skip command