# Search for content and print error if not readable

Tags: bash, shell

I cannot figure out how to solve this problem. I got a function, and I send to it a directory and a word. I want to search all files in that directory which contain that word, but if I can not read them, I want to print my own error. Here is what I have:

`find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "$2" || error 3 "You can not read the archive."`

Where:

- $1 -> Directory
- $2 -> Word to search.

It works, but the point is that I got the grep error if I find a non-readable file, and I dont want it to appear. Do you know what can I do in order to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Ok and if I use this:

`result=$(find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -s "$2" || error 3 "You can not read the archive.")`

It only saves the error once, how can I do it if I want to print the error once for every archive?

Comment: You will find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, two options come to mind:

1) Redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` (`/dev/null` being the null device, which "discards" any input sent to it), for example:

```
grep "$2" 2> /dev/null
```

2) If you are using `GNU` `grep`, then the option `grep -s` would work for you, for example:

```
grep -s "$2"
```

From the `grep` manual:

> -s, --no-messages
>       Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files. Portability note: unlike GNU grep, 7th Edition Unix grep did not
>   conform to POSIX , because it lacked -q and its -s option behaved like
>   GNU grep's -q option. USG -style grep also lacked -q but its -s option
>   behaved like GNU grep. Portable shell scripts should avoid both -q and
>   -s and should redirect standard and error output to /dev/null instead. (-s is specified by POSIX .)

Comment: Thank you very much!! I didn't know grep has that.

Comment: Ok and if I use this:
result=$(find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -s "$2" || error 3 "You can not read the archive.")
It only saves the error once, how can I solve this?

Comment: Since this is a different problem, I suggest that you revert your current question back to the original and after that post a new question with the new problem on SO -- new questions get all the attention and answers from the community. Also, by doing that it would make my answer "make sense" again, since when I answered it there was only the `grep` error problem.