# Remove some lines of output from find(shell) command

Tags: git, bash, shell

I am trying to find the list of all git repositories on my local machine. I do get all of them but I also get some repositories which have Permission denied in the output

```
find . -name .git -type d -prune | sed '/Permission/d'
```

The output of the command is

```
find: ./.Trash/Fuze_old.app/Contents/Frameworks/Fuze Helper.app: Permission denied
./.nvm/.git
./.oh-my-zsh/.git
./.Trash/AutoLayout/.git
./.Trash/DemoProject/.git
find: ./Library/Python: Permission denied
./.Trash/NavView/.git
./.Trash/Something/.git
./.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/.git
```

I do not want the lines with Permission denied.

How do I get that?

Comment: Those probably go to stderr and you can discard them with `2> /dev/null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I exclude all "permission denied" messages from "find"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find)

Answer (score 4):

The "permission denied" lines are likely on STDERR instead of STDOUT, which is why your `sed` command is ineffective.  Try this (if you're on a Unix-like system):

```
find . -name .git -type d -prune 2>/dev/null
```