# Is there a way to filter output of bash 'find' command to exclude results with "permission denied"?

Tags: bash, find, filesystems

When I want to find a file I use the command `find <directory> -name <filename>`. Often the command will output multiple lines with "Permission Denied" at the end. Is there a way to filter the results to exclude these lines?

Comment: `find ... 2> /dev/null` maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I exclude all "permission denied" messages from "find"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find)

Answer (score 1):

**This will work**

```
find <directory> -name <filename> 2>/dev/null
```

**Example**

```
[test@satellite ~]$ find / -name test
find: ‘/boot/grub2’: Permission denied
find: ‘/proc/tty/driver’: Permission denied
find: ‘/proc/1/task/1/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘/proc/1/task/1/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘/proc/1/task/1/ns’: Permission denied
```

**When `2>/dev/null` is used**

```
[test@satellite ~]$ find / -name test 2>/dev/null
/var/spool/mail/test
/usr/bin/test
/usr/lib64/python2.7/test
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/test
/usr/lib64/python2.7/unittest/test
/usr/share/doc/jsr-305-0/sampleUses/test
```